# Local executing hook after a git push? (post-push)

Tags: git, githooks

I've looked at [the githooks manpage](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) but unless I'm missing something I don't see an option for local, post-push git hooks.  I'd like to have one that updates the api docs on my web server (for which I already have a script) after I push the master branch to the GitHub repo.  Of course I could just write my own script that combines the git push and the api docs run, but that feels somewhat inelegant.

Comment: the `post-update` hooks can be triggered for this case right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From Git 1.8.2 there is a new hook invoked before the push operation: **pre-push** If the script returns other than 0 the push operation will be cancelled.

Mention in the release notes: https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.2.txt#L167

Sample: https://github.com/git/git/blob/87c86dd14abe8db7d00b0df5661ef8cf147a72a3/templates/hooks--pre-push.sample

Comment: I don't thing this answer is the good one, it tells about the pre-push hook, and the original question was about post-push hook.

Comment: Levente Holló,the pre-push hook is executed after the user runs `git-push` and before git actually pushes the commit/s.There is no other push related hook integrated in Git.

Answer (score 56):

Another solution to this problem is to have a wrapper for `git push` that executes `.git/hooks/pre-push` and `.git/hooks/post-push` scripts before and after the `git push` call. A possible wrapper could look like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

GIT_DIR_="$(git rev-parse --git-dir)"
BRANCH="$(git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref $(git symbolic-ref HEAD))"

PRE_PUSH="$GIT_DIR_/hooks/pre-push"
POST_PUSH="$GIT_DIR_/hooks/post-push"

test -x "$PRE_PUSH" &&
    exec "$PRE_PUSH" "$BRANCH" "$@"

git push "$@"

test $? -eq 0 && test -x "$POST_PUSH" &&
    exec "$POST_PUSH" "$BRANCH" "$@"
```

Saved as `git-push-wh` somewhere in your `PATH`, it can then be called as `git push-wh` if you want to push with hooks.

Comment: This is brilliant...

I use separate remotes: one where I host my code, a bare repo in my production server so I added [this code](https://gist.github.com/SaifurRahmanMohsin/0a6d1944cbd7815e58e7) to my [~/.functions.sh](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/dotfiles) and use

** push origin **
** push production **

it automatically launches the website (since that’s defined in push-post) in my browser once the push completes. Thanks!

Comment: Current code does not work in git worktrees, to fix it, just change 3 lines:
`
GIT_DIR_="$(git rev-parse --git-path hooks)"

PRE_PUSH="${GIT_DIR_}/pre-push"
POST_PUSH="${GIT_DIR_}/post-push"
`

Answer (score 39):

I recently came across the same issue. I wanted a hook so that a push from my git submodule would commit the new submodule reference in the 'superproject'.

As Chris mentioned, the best way is to just use a git alias, like this:

```
$ git config alias.xpush '!git push $1 $2 && update-server.sh'
# (remember the backslash before the ! if your shell requires it)
```

This adds the following to your .git/config file:

```
[alias]
  xpush = !git push $1 $2 && update-server.sh
```

And so now, if you type:

```
$ git xpush
```

your changes will be pushed, and then update-server.sh will be executed.

Comment: Umm what about if you are in a branch? and you do  that xpush?  shouldn't be something like  !git push $1 $2 && update-server.sh  so you can specify origin branch?

Comment: Note that overriding an existing command is not possible with a git alias, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538774/is-it-possible-to-override-git-command-by-git-alias

Answer (score 36):

This type of hook is not supported by Git. It falls outside the [valid reasons for a Git hook](https://lore.kernel.org/git/7vzlvns11r.fsf@gitster.siamese.dyndns.org/)
 as given by Git's maintainer.

The introductory remark in the above linked message speaks almost directly to your case:

> I do not particularly like hooks that
>   act after an operation is initiated
>   locally and act solely on local data. 
>   This is maybe because I still consider
>   git tools building blocks suitable for
>   higher level scripting more than other
>   people do.

#### P.S. A “Single Push” Hint

- There are too many caveats for a full explanation, but if you can figure it all out you should be able to deal with the details.

An extra `pushurl` to a local repo with an “alternates” objects store could give you a low overhead way to locally execute a push hook. But really, the effort is much more than `git push upstream && update-web-server` (maybe in a shell alias, git alias, or script).

Comment: Same information can be found in: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/71069

Comment: Please, notice that from 1.8.2 Git added a **pre-push** hook. Check my answer to find more information.

Answer (score 7):

Implementing a post-push hook is in fact possible by using the `reference-transaction` hook. After a push is done, git will locally update the remote tracking branch, triggering a reference transaction on `refs/remotes/REMOTE/BRANCH`.

Here's an example for a hook that uses this technique:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -eu

while read oldvalue newvalue refname
do
    if [ $1 = committed -a $refname = refs/remotes/origin/main ]
    then
        exec .git/hooks/post-push
    fi
done
```

This script must have the executable bit and be placed in `.git/hooks/reference-transaction`. The hook runs after pushing the main branch to origin. Put your actual hook script in `.git/hooks/post-push`.

Comment: Perfect!  To me, this should be be the ✅ accepted answer!  I just put my own command on the line where it says `exec .git/hooks/post-push` instead of creating another file.  Push to deploy via remote ssh command: Achieved. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'm using a function for this:

```
current_branch() {
    local ref=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD 2> /dev/null) || return
    echo ${ref#refs/heads/}
}

gp() {
    local post_push="$(git rev-parse --git-dir)/hooks/post-push"
    git push "$@" && {
        [[ -x "$post_push" ]] && "$post_push" "$(current_branch)" "$@"
    }
}
compdef _git gp=git-push
```

The compdef part is for ZSH.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a `pre-push` hook with a sleep at the top. Ensure sleep is long enough for the commits to be uploaded to upstream server based on your network connection speed. Ideally add a `&` to run your script in the background:

```
(sleep 30 && .git/hooks/post-push) &
```

Answer (score 1):

`incron` to the rescue.

my `incrontab` has this:

```
/path/to/.git/logs/refs/remotes/origin IN_CLOSE_WRITE /usr/local/bin/git-post-push $@/$#
```

The script checks whether the remote changed by a push and if yes extracts a few helpful things with GNU grep:

```
# The script is called with a filename like /path/to/.git/logs/refs/remotes/origin/main
# Each lines of the file is, as per https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-ref#_logging_updates:
# oldsha1 SP newsha1 SP committer TAB message LF
# "committer" is the committer’s name, email address, the Unix timestamp and 
# the timezone, all separated by spaces.
# git push uses the literal text "update by push" without quotes as message.
push=$(tail -1 "$1"| grep -oP '\d{10}(?=\s.{1,5}\supdate by push$)')
if [ -n "$push" ]; then
  gitdir=$(echo "$1"|grep -oP '^.*/.git/')
  remote=$(echo "$1"|grep -oP '.git/logs/refs/remotes/\K[^/]+')
  branch=$(echo "$1"|grep -oP '.git/logs/refs/remotes/[^/]+/\K.*$')
  # your code here
  # git --git-dir="$gitdir"....
fi
```

The `push` variable contains the timestamp of the push, the rest is self explanatory.