# How to avoid having to do "git branch --set-upstream", and instead default to automatically setup remote tracking?

Tags: git, git-branch

I create a new branch in Git:

```
git branch my_branch
```

Push it:

```
git push origin my_branch
```

Now say someone made some changes on the server and I want to pull from `origin/my_branch`. I do:

```
git pull
```

But I get:

```
You asked me to pull without telling me which branch you
want to merge with, and 'branch.my_branch.merge' in
your configuration file does not tell me, either. Please
specify which branch you want to use on the command line and
try again (e.g. 'git pull <repository> <refspec>').
See git-pull(1) for details.

If you often merge with the same branch, you may want to
use something like the following in your configuration file:

    [branch "my_branch"]
    remote = <nickname>
    merge = <remote-ref>

    [remote "<nickname>"]
    url = <url>
    fetch = <refspec>

See git-config(1) for details.
```

I learned that I can make it work with:

```
git branch --set-upstream my_branch origin/my_branch
```

But why do I need to do this for every branch I create? Isn't it obvious that if I push `my_branch` into `origin/my_branch`, then I would want to pull `origin/my_branch` into `my_branch`? How can I make this the default behavior?

Comment: The default for `branch.autosetupmerge` means that the upstream configuration for a new branch is only automatically set when creating a branch from a remote-tracking branch (e.g. `<remote-name>/<branch-name>`) (see *[git-config(1)](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html)*). You are probably creating your branches from existing local branches. If you are effectively branching directly from the tip of a remote branch (despite being on a local branch), then you can use `git branch my_branch <remote-name>/<branch-name>` to automatically setup the upstream configuration.

Comment: FYI, the `--set-upstream` option is deprecated. You should use `--track` or `--set-upstream-to` instead.

Comment: if `--set-upstream` is deprecated, then perhaps the git devs should remove it from the help message that gets displayed when you run `git push` with no options and no upstream is set?

Comment: @ChristopherHunter It's been over a year since your comment and it **still** says that. Is it just a sloppy feedback or perhaps is there a technically wise reason to keep it around that we're ignorant about?

Comment: For others looking for a more recent one-liner (post git 2.0): `BRANCH=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD) && git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/$BRANCH $BRANCH`

Comment: @ChristopherHunter: You meant `git pull` rather than `git push`, right?

Comment: @LarsH, no I mean `git push`. Specifically the modern usage to set the upstream branch to which you want to push, is `git push -u origin branchname`, as described in the answer by @Mark Longair. With `git pull`, the `-u` does a different thing, and I find that I would rather specify each time what branch to pull from anyway.

Comment: @ChristopherHunter `git branch --set-upstream` is deprecated. `git push --set-upstream` is not.

Comment: Git stopped supporting the `--set-upstream` option. `branch --set-upstream` has been deprecated in Git 1.8 and  had finally been retired in  Git 2.15 on Nov 2017.

Comment: @JarekPrzygódzki presumably you mean `git branch --set-upstream-to`? Or perhaps `git push --set-upstream`? I'm not sure ... but my installed Git 2.25 doesn't seem to be aware that this has been retired 

Comment: I know about git `upstream` related to [`forking`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9257901/1705829) in git, but this context is not meant here. So I also wonder why `upstream` is needed here.

Comment: Eleven years later, with Git 2.37 (Q3 2022), a simple [`git config --global push.autoSetupRemote`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72401899/6309) is enough!

Answer (score 2000, accepted):

#### Git v2.37.1 and above

If you are using the mentioned version or above you can use this new config entry to automatically setup remote tracking:

`git config --global push.autoSetupRemote true`

After that, when you do `git push` tracking is setup automatically. No need for `git push -u origin my_branch`

---

A shortcut, which doesn't depend on remembering the syntax for `git branch --set-upstream` <sup>1</sup> is to do:

```
git push -u origin my_branch
```

... the first time that you push that branch. Or, to push to the current branch from a branch of the same name (handy for an alias):

```
git push -u origin HEAD
```

You only need to use `-u` once, and that sets up the association between your branch and the one at `origin` in the same way as `git branch --set-upstream` does.

Personally, I think it's a good thing to have to set up that association between your branch and one on the remote explicitly.  It's just a shame that the rules are [different for `git push` and `git pull`](http://longair.net/blog/2011/02/27/an-asymmetry-between-git-pull-and-git-push/).

---

<sup>1</sup> It may sound silly, but I very frequently forget to specify the current branch, assuming that's the default - it's not, and the results are most confusing.

*Update 2012-10-11*: Apparently I'm not the only person who found it easy to get wrong! Thanks to [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc) for pointing out that git 1.8.0 introduces the more obvious `git branch --set-upstream-to`, which can be used as follows, if you're on the branch `my_branch`:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to origin/my_branch
```

... or with the short option:

```
git branch -u origin/my_branch
```

This change, and its reasoning, is described in [the release notes for git 1.8.0, release candidate 1](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.0.txt):

> It was tempting to say `git branch --set-upstream origin/master`, but that tells Git to arrange the local branch `origin/master` to integrate with the currently checked out branch, which is highly unlikely to be what the user meant. The option is deprecated; use the new `--set-upstream-to` (with a short-and-sweet `-u`) option instead.

Comment: Also note that even if you forget the `-u` the first time you push, you can run the push again with that flag and it will start tracking.

Comment: None of these satisfy the use-case of using git push without arguments. It remains that I still have to remember to 'git push -u origin my-branch' when moving my new branch to the remote for the first time.

Comment: @KarlthePagan When you create a remote-tracking local branch, you tell git you want to create a new branch, and you name the remote repo and branch.  When you create a tracked remote branch, you tell git you want to create a new branch, and you name the remote repo and branch.  In both cases, git properly defaults the branch name.  Localized conveniences like what you're asking for is exactly what [git aliases](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Aliases) are for.

Comment: Note to self: a more complete explanation for the first `git push -u origin master`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17096880/6309

Comment: I hate remembering that syntax as well, so I created the following alias: `alias gpo="git push --set-upstream origin $(git branch | awk '/^\* / { print $2 }')"`

Comment: Here I always set it with my first push this way : `git push -u origin --all` which makes my life much easier...

Comment: This is all fine, but I still think the OP's complaint is valid.  You start a local branch, work on it, push it to origin to share (with no args); why shouldn't that set the upstream?  Is it actually desirable for some reason NOT to set upstream when pushing a new branch to a remote?

Comment: @lillialexis, thanks for that tip. I hate seeing `Branch foo set up to track remote branch foo from origin.` every time, so I came up with `alias gu="git push --set-upstream origin $(git branch | awk '/^\* / { print $2 }') >> /dev/null"` You can still see the output, but you don't see the redundant messages.

Comment: A more correct answer to the question asked is given below by @Zamith. Set your global config so that you don't have to type anything.

Comment: Since I haven't seen it stated here, you can also define the local and remote branches to associate without checking out the desired tracking branch like so. `git branch --set-upstream <local-branch> <remote/branch>`. For example `git branch --set-upstream master origin/production` Should result in `Branch master set up to track remote branch production from origin.`

Comment: @fyrye I'm wondering if and how it's possible without using `--set-upstream` which is deprecated now?

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost The syntax for 1.8+ is `git branch [-u|--set-upstream-to]` for the alternative. As stated in the answer. My comment is about  assigning the associated branch without checking out the desired tracking branch. So `git branch --set-upstram-to=origin/production master` or `git branch -u origin/production master`

Comment: one further shortcut/tweak is `git push -u origin HEAD` ... This allows you to skip typing your branch name. You *do* need to make sure you are on the right branch.

Comment: What you said may not be correct on git 2.15.1, I got MacBook-Pro:autoservice$ git branch -u origin/restrict
error: the requested upstream branch 'origin/restrict' does not exist
hint: 
hint: If you are planning on basing your work on an upstream
hint: branch that already exists at the remote, you may need to
hint: run "git fetch" to retrieve it.
hint: 
hint: If you are planning to push out a new local branch that
hint: will track its remote counterpart, you may want to use
hint: "git push -u" to set the upstream config as you push.

Comment: @user204069 Have you tried what the error message you got suggests? (That is, either: running `git fetch origin` before trying that command, if the branch `restrict` already exists in the origin repository, or pushing it with `git push -u origin restrict` instead, in which case you wouldn't need the `git branch -u`.)

Comment: @GaryO it is desirable not to mess the remote repository. See an explanation of why `git push -u origin master` is needed in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/17096880/2641825 also mentioned by VonC above.

Comment: *"It's just a shame that the rules are different for git push and git pull."* -- I can empathize with a lot of beginners on this statement, but I personally disagree. I personally like `push.default = current`. I like to push to the same-named branch, but pull from the tracking branch. This lets me do a `git rebase @{u}` when I do a `git pull` but push to my `topic` branch when I do `git push`. I love this workflow for fork-based model.

Comment: It would be convenient if this answer were updated to reflect the "push.autoSetupRemote" option introduced in 2.37, as noted by VonC in https://stackoverflow.com/a/72401899/74296

Comment: I'm using git v2.39.2 and this does not work. It continues to give the `There is no tracking information for the current branch.` error until you manually link the local and remote branches. I still don't understand why this behavior exists at all, much less why it's the default.

Comment: NOTE: after `git config --global push.autoSetupRemote true`, you have to do a `git push` before your `git pull` starts to work...

Comment: This doesn't seem to work the same as `--set-upstream`. Specifically, `git status` still says "Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit." after `git push origin "$(git branch --show-current)"`.

Answer (score 1800):

You can make this happen with less typing. First, change the way your push works:

```
git config --global push.default current
```

This will infer the `origin my_branch` part, thus you can do:

```
git push -u
```

Which will both create the remote branch with the same name and track it.

Comment: How come can git infer `origin` when running `git push -u` for newly created branch in newly created repository? Is the assumption that repository had been cloned thus current branch has its remote set to `origin`?

Comment: `git push -u` set tracking to local branch with the same name, not even remote.

Comment: Did you set the `push.default` config? Also, do you have the remote set up?

Comment: This should be the default. So many things in git could be more user-friendly if it just shipped with better defaults.

Comment: Be aware that 'current' is slightly unsafer than using 'simple' to do the same thing, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23918062/simple-vs-current-push-default-in-git-for-decentralized-workflow

Comment: It does, but then when you try to `pull` you'll have to specify from where. The `-u` sets up the branch tracking between origin and your local repo.

Comment: @mottlard It also doesn't answer the OP's actual question, which is (paraphrased) _"How does one make git default to tracking the remote branch that's created when one pushes a local branch to the remote for the first time?"_. The `-u` option is all very well but what's the rationale for not having this as the default behaviour in the first place?

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost adding phreakhead answer, when cloning a repo, git also automatically add the URI as remote with the name origin. I think origin is some defaults for remote repository

Comment: @Yana Yes, you can name a remote whatever you want. `origin` happens to be the default that git uses.

Comment: There is a further [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/948397/175584) that explains that `simple` is the default config value so beginners don't mess things up. Therefore for more advanced usage setting it to `current` then makes sense as it's `simple` mode with the addition of creating an upstream branch, if doesn't exist.

Comment: @pstryk Yes it will work without `-u` but then it would not be tracking the upsteam branch for any changes, depends whether you care about that or not...

Comment: This should be the accepted answer - setting this default will make `git push` work as they expected with a new local branch. And as mentioned above, this will work without `-u`

Comment: While marginally convenient, this *still* mandates that a different command be run for the first and only `push`– which defeats the entire point of this question. In short, **there is no good answer.** That Git developers insist on retaining this Awkward User eXperience (AUX) in the face of widespread community dissent is... enlightening. And discouraging. (Mostly discouraging.)

Comment: why use global config if you have multiple git projects set up in your machine?

Comment: @ParamvirSinghKarwal you can add it as a config for each project. I however, want this to be the default behavior in all my projects, thus the global setting.

Comment: the number of times I've returned to this answer makes me disappointed in the state of user experience for developer tools ‍♂️

Comment: `git config --global push.default upstream` i think is more what we're looking for here.

Answer (score 215):

This is my most common use for [The Fuck](https://github.com/nvbn/thefuck).

```
$ git push
fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin master

$ fuck
git push --set-upstream origin master [enter/↑/↓/ctrl+c]
Counting objects: 9, done.
...
```

Also, it's fun to type swear words in your terminal.

Comment: Fun fact: only 2.4% of programmers disagree with the last statement

Comment: If you are pair programming you might want to set a different alias :-D To do that you can set the alias in your `.bashrc` or .`zshrc` config like this

`eval $(thefuck --alias fix)`

I have set the alias as "fix" instead of the default one "fuck"

Ref - https://github.com/nvbn/thefuck#manual-installation

Answer (score 121):

```
git config --global push.autoSetupRemote true
```

---

The OP asks:

> I learned that I can make it work with:
>
> ```
> git branch --set-upstream my_branch origin/my_branch
> ```
>
> But why do I need to do this for every branch I create?

You do not need to set upstream all the time.
Not anymore (eleven years later).

With Git 2.37 (Q3 2022), a **`git config --global push.autoSetupRemote true`** will take care of that for you.

See [commit 05d5775](https://github.com/git/git/commit/05d57750c66e4b58233787954c06b8f714bbee75), [commit 8a649be](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8a649be7e8010085a8a3f1c9126da5c02324350e), [commit bdaf1df](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bdaf1dfae71fdf120fc7253e713ccf0a06cc5558) (29 Apr 2022) by [Tao Klerks (`TaoK`)](https://github.com/TaoK).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit f49c478](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f49c478f628910de206c5e882a3cd3abec76d4e6), 26 May 2022)</sup>

> ### [`push`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/05d57750c66e4b58233787954c06b8f714bbee75): new config option "`push.autoSetupRemote`" supports "`simple`" push
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Tao Klerks</sup>

> In some "`simple`" centralized workflows, users expect remote tracking branch names to match local branch names.
> "[`git push`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/05d57750c66e4b58233787954c06b8f714bbee75/Documentation/git-push.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push))</sup> pushes to the remote version/instance of the branch, and "[`git pull`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/05d57750c66e4b58233787954c06b8f714bbee75/Documentation/git-pull.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull))</sup> pulls any changes to the remote branch (changes made by the same user in another place, or by other users).
>
> This expectation is supported by the `push.default` default option "`simple`" which refuses a default push for a mismatching tracking branch name, and by the new `branch.autosetupmerge` option, "`simple`", which only sets up remote tracking for same-name remote branches.
>
> When a new branch has been created by the user and has not yet been pushed (and `push.default` is not set to "`current`"), the user is prompted with a "`The current branch %s has no upstream branch`" error, and instructions on how to push and add tracking.
>
> This error is helpful in that following the advice once per branch "resolves" the issue for that branch forever, but inconvenient in that for the "simple" centralized workflow, this is always the right thing to do, so it would be better to just do it.
>
> Support this workflow with a new config setting, `push.autoSetupRemote`, which will cause a default push, when there is no remote tracking branch configured, to push to the same-name on the remote and `--set-upstream`.
>
> Also add a hint offering this new option when the "`The current branch %s has no upstream branch`" error is encountered, and add corresponding tests.

The new hint is:

> To have this happen automatically for branches without a tracking
> upstream, see '`push.autoSetupRemote`' in 'git help config'

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/05d57750c66e4b58233787954c06b8f714bbee75/Documentation/config/push.txt#L1-L11):

> ### `push.autoSetupRemote`
>
> If set to "`true`" assume `--set-upstream` on default push when no
> upstream tracking exists for the current branch;
>
> This option takes effect with `push.default` options '`simple`', '`upstream`', and '`current`'.
>
> It is useful if by default you want new branches to be pushed to the default remote (like the behavior of '`push.default=current`') and you also want the upstream tracking to be set.
> Workflows most likely to benefit from this option are '`simple`' central workflows where all branches are expected to have the same name on the remote.

Comment: This answer should be the accepted one: doing `git config --global push.autoSetupRemote always` will let you auto track origin as soon as you push a branch/commit.

Comment: Using git v2.39.2 on a Mac this does not work. It continues to give the `There is no tracking information for the current branch.` error.

Comment: @thomasruns Strange, do you have a `push.default` config set?

Answer (score 105):

You can simply

```
git checkout -b my-branch origin/whatever
```

in the first place. If you set `branch.autosetupmerge` or `branch.autosetuprebase` (my favorite) to `always` (default is `true`), `my-branch` will automatically track `origin/whatever`.

See `git help config`.

Comment: This produces "fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'my-branch' at the same time."

Comment: @Karl, that rare error is explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/945654/git-checkout-on-a-remote-branch-does-not-work).

Comment: By the way, I usually just `git checkout -t origin/whatever`, which also chooses `whatever` as the new branch-name. Very convenient!

Comment: @cdunn This one is ideal, but hardly consistent.  The flag should be called `-u`/`--set-upstream`.

Comment: `git checkout -t origin/whatever` doesn't work for me when trying to create a new branch: `fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'whatever' at the same time.`

Comment: `git checkout -b my-branch origin/whatever` also has the same error (I'm trying to create a new branch that doesn't exist on local or remote):  `fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'whatever' at the same time.`

Comment: `branch.autosetupmerge = false` did not work either. It set the upstream tracking to local `whatever` branch instead of remote `origin/whatever`.

Answer (score 93):

You can set upstream simpler in two ways. First when you create the branch:

```
git branch -u origin/my-branch
```

or after you have created a branch, you can use this command.

```
git push -u origin my-branch
```

You can also branch, check out and set upstream in a single command:

```
git checkout -b my-branch -t origin/my-branch
```

My personally preference is to do this in a two-step command:

```
git checkout -b my-branch
git push -u origin my-branch
```

Comment: Great answer! Addresses both common use cases. After running `git branch -u origin/my-branch` I can run `git pull` to pull down my changes.

Comment: "git checkout -b my-branch -t origin/my-branch" this doesn't work if 'origin/my-branch' doesn't exist yet.

Comment: You actually can just do `git checkout -t origin/my-branch` without the `-b my-branch`, it will just automatically infer `my-branch` for the local branch name. However, as @Spongman mentioned, this command doesn't work if `origin/my-branch` doesn't exist first.

Comment: Yes, will work @wisbucky, -t works just fine.
Personally though, even two years after I wrote that reply though, I still prefer splitting in two lines with checkout -b and push -u. It is more explicit and no error on checkout -b when I don't have remote - which happens quite often when experimenting :)

Comment: `git push -u origin/my-branch` fails for me with `fatal: 'origin/my-branch' does not appear to be a git repository`. This works: `git push -u origin my-branch`

Comment: Using git v.2.34.1 on MacOS single line option fails like this:
git status
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
git checkout -b my-branch -t origin/my-branch
fatal: 'origin/my-branch' is not a commit and a branch 'my-branch' cannot be created from it

Answer (score 66):

You can use:

```
git config --global branch.autosetupmerge always
```

which will link the upstream branch each time you create or checkout a new branch.

See https://felipec.wordpress.com/2013/09/01/advanced-git-concepts-the-upstream-tracking-branch/

This also works with `branch.autosetuprebase`, if you follow a more rebase focused workflow, but don't use this unless you know what you're doing, as it will default your pull behavior to rebase, which can cause odd results.

Comment: Doesn't work, I still get the `--set-upstream` message

Comment: @Dorian, You have to set this before you create the branch. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9753268/263998

Comment: I get: fatal: The upstream branch of your current branch does not match the name of your current branch...

Comment: but this does not set the tracking branch as the remote with the same branch, but to the current local branch.. so when you do push it will try to push to the LOCAL branch you was before creating the new branch..

Comment: **Be Careful** with this setting!! After setting it, you get this behaviour. 1. Switch to `master`. 2. Run `git checkout -b new_branch`. 3. Add a commit to that branch. 4. `git push origin new_branch`. **This pushes that commit to the `master` branch on origin** (rather than to a new branch on origin called `new_branch`).

Answer (score 43):

By the way, the shortcut to pushing the current branch to a remote with the same name:

```
$ git push -u origin HEAD
```

Answer (score 36):

I personally use these following alias in bash

**in ~/.gitconfig file**

```
[alias]
    pushup = "!git push --set-upstream origin $(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD)"
```

**and in ~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc file**

```
alias gpo="git pushup"
alias gpof="gpo -f"
alias gf="git fetch"
alias gp="git pull"
```

Comment: I only needed to hcange .gitconfig, then I could use the command `git pushup` which always pushes the current branch to the origin. I can always just use `git pushup` instead of `git push` 

Comment: just expanding on this answer to setup a global git alias (custom commands) - `git config --global alias.pushup  "!git push --set-upstream origin $(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD)"`

Answer (score 35):

If the below doesn't work:

```
git config --global push.default current
```

You should also update your project's local config, as its possible your project has local git configurations:

```
git config --local push.default current
```

Comment: More explanations would be great. What does the first line do?

Comment: This answer is the one that feels legit. All the ones proposing aliases are dumb workarounds. And the other ones justifying memorizing long command sequences are pedantic.

Comment: This works for pushing but not pulling. It uses the correct upstream when you push, but doesn't set the upstream, so you still have to run a command to set the upstream before you can pull a branch for the first time.

Comment: @rspeer not sure what you mean? This works for pull, but if you haven't done a fetch (or pull that also does fetch), you can not checkout a branch that was created remotely since last time you did a fetch - has and will always be the case. You could argue it's worth having a habit of running `git fetch --prune`, so you also get remote branches deleted locally if they are deleted remotely.

Comment: @JohnySkovdal What I mean is: if you run this configuration, create a branch, and push that branch, you cannot pull updates to that same branch that you created, because you didn't set its upstream. Lots of workflows could benefit from a way of automatically setting the upstream, which is what the question asked for.

Comment: So this answer is "hey, you don't need to set the upstream, here's a config option that lets you push without setting the upstream". But it doesn't let you pull, so it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @rspeer I stand corrected. I could have _sworn_ it worked for pull too, but apparently when I've needed to collab on a branch, I've used GUI tools that fixed it for me without knowing. Else my workflow has always been one person per branch, so haven't run into this limitation in CLI before... Then I agree, this isn't an answer to the question the OP was asking.

Answer (score 12):

For what it is worth, if you are trying to track a branch that already exists on the remote (eg. origin/somebranch) but haven't checked it out locally yet, you can do:

```
$ git checkout --track origin/somebranch
```

Note: '-t' is the shortened version of '--track' option.

This sets up the same association right off the bat.

Comment: You can actually just checkout to the branch. So `git checkout somebranch` is equivalent.

Comment: @Zamith Doesn't that only work after having called `git fetch` immediately beforehand?

Comment: Not immediately, but yes, you do need to have a reference to that branch on your local repo, which happens whenever you call `git fetch` or `git pull`. I've never found that to be an issue, though.

Answer (score 12):

**Update:** `push.autoSetupRemote` now solves this in an easier way, finally! See the [other answer on that here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72401899/2544629) for more information.

**Original answer:**

I use this Git alias instead of copy/pasting the suggestion from Git every time: https://gist.github.com/ekilah/88a880c84a50b73bd306

Source copied below (add this to your `~/.gitconfig` file):

```
[alias]
  pushup = "!gitbranchname() { git symbolic-ref --short HEAD; }; gitpushupstream() { git push --set-upstream origin `gitbranchname`; }; gitpushupstream"
```

Answer (score 10):

You can also explicitly tell git pull what remote branch to pull (as it mentions in the error message):

`git pull <remote-name> <remote-branch>`

*Be careful with this, however:* if you are on a different branch and do an explicit pull, the refspec you pull will be merged into the branch you're on!

Answer (score 10):

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master<branch_name>
```

Comment: Not supported anymore.

Answer (score 7):

You can set up a really good alias that can handle this without the overly verbose syntax.

I have the following alias in `~/.gitconfig`:

```
po = "!git push -u origin \"$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)\""
```

After making a commit on a new branch, you can push your new branch by simply typing the command:

```
git po
```

Comment: why `po`? `push origin`? what happen if this is ran multiple times?

Comment: Yes, as in push origin.  Nothing happens if it's run multiple times.  I also have a `git push -f` alias set up to `git pf`, so I use that once the origin has already been pushed.

Comment: see [djanowski's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089294/why-do-i-need-to-do-set-upstream-all-the-time#39513531), you can directly use `HEAD`

Answer (score 6):

I did something similar to a lot of other users but wanted to share it as an alternative since I didn't see anyone else post this.

```
alias gpu='git push --set-upstream origin $(git branch --show-current)'
```

(oh-my-zsh already has a gpu alias so edited that in .oh-my-zsh/plugins/git/git.plugin.zsh)

Answer (score 5):

For those looking for an alias that works with `git pull`, this is what I use:

```
alias up="git branch | awk '/^\\* / { print \$2 }' | xargs -I {} git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/{} {}"
```

Now whenever you get:

```
$ git pull
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
...
```

Just run:

```
$ up
Branch my_branch set up to track remote branch my_branch from origin.
$ git pull
```

And you're good to go

Answer (score 5):

In git `2.37.0` or newer, you can tell git to automatically setup the remote. This is done with

```
git config --global --add --bool push.autoSetupRemote true
```

Then you can just write `git push` and it will push to the default remote.

Comment: Yes, I [already documented that new option on this very same page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72401899/6309).

Comment: Sure. I just thought your answer was a bit too verbose.

Comment: This answer should cover 90-99 % of people's use of this feature. For a deeper explanation, the answer from @VonC.

Comment: But what is "the default remote"? I need to know if this sets main (master) as the default.

Answer (score 4):

99% of the time I want to set the upstream to a *branch of the same name*, so I use this (in *nix or Git Bash):

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/$(git branch --show-current)
```

It's nice because it's branch agnostic. Note the sub-command `git branch --show-current` prints your current branch name, or nothing if you are detached.

**Side note**: I have my config set such that I can use `git push -u`, so I rarely need to do this. But I still do sometimes, and it's usually when I decide I want to reset my local changes to whatever's on the remote, and at that moment I realize I previously pushed without -u. So, typically the next command I'm going to run after setting my upstream, is resetting to the remote branch:

```
git reset --hard @{u}
```

Which also happens to be branch agnostic. (Maybe I just really dislike typing in my branch name.)

Comment: Got `error: the requested upstream branch 'origin/test' does not exist`

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich that means you haven't pushed your branch yet. (This question was about setting your upstream *after* you already pushed the branch.) In your case you can set the upstream on the first push, something like `git push --set-upstream origin test`

Comment: But can I set upstream without push/pull? I want to have an alias that will create a new branch and set the upstream, currently I have this broken code: `[alias]
 cr = "!f() { git switch -c $1; git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master $1; }; f"
`

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich I don't know of a good way to say "this is what I *will* want to track once I push it." I suppose you could update your alias to push it out at branch creation with the upstream set, though it might be odd to announce a new branch name with no new commits on it yet, but at least it would accomplish your goal...

Answer (score 3):

[oh-my-zsh's git plugin](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master/plugins/git) already has this aliased as `gpsup`. This pushes and sets the upstream to the branch. All in one go!

I personally dig solutions that are standardized and consistent. Would recommend others to use the same alias. :)

Answer (score 3):

you can let git create an upstream branch automatically by running either of the following git commands

1. git config --global --add push.default current
2. git config --global --add push.autoSetupRemote true

Answer (score 2):

Because git has the cool ability to push/pull different branches to different "upstream" repositories. You could even use separate repositories for pushing and pulling - on the same branch. This can create a distributed, multi-level flow, I can see this being useful on project such as the Linux kernel. Git was originally built to be used on that project.

As a consequence, it does not make assumption about which repo your branch should be tracking.

On the other hand, most people do not use git in this way, so it might make a good case for a default option.

Git is generally pretty low-level and it can be frustrating. Yet there are GUIs and it should be easy to write helper scripts if you still want to use it from the shell.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do `git push -u origin $(current_branch)`

Answer (score 1):

We use phabricator and don't push using git. I had to create bash alias which works on Linux/mac

```
vim ~/.bash_aliases

new_branch() {
    git checkout -b "$1"
    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master "$1"
}
```

save

```
source ~/.bash_aliases
new_branch test #instead of git checkout -b test
git pull
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a bash alias for git push which is safe to run for every push and will automatically switch between setting upstream for the first push and then doing normal pushes after that.

```
alias gpu='[[ -z $(git config "branch.$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD).merge") ]] && git push -u origin $(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD) || git push'
```

[Original Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19021888/3854385)

Comment: Got `error: the requested upstream branch 'origin/test' does not exist`

Answer (score 1):

All i wanted was doing something like this:

```sh
git checkout -b my-branch
git commit -a -m "my commit"
git push
```

Since i didn't found a better solution, i've just created an bash alias on `~/.bashrc`:

```sh
alias push="git push -u origin HEAD"
```

now just doing a `push` command does the job (you can add this alias on `~/.gitconfig` too with another name, such as `pushup`)

Answer (score 0):

I sort of re-discovered [`legit`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/legit) because of this issue (OS X only). Now all I use when branching are these two commands:

`legit publish [<branch>]`
    Publishes specified branch to the remote. (alias: `pub`)

`legit unpublish <branch>`
    Removes specified branch from the remote. (alias: `unp`)

[SublimeGit](https://github.com/SublimeGit/SublimeGit/) comes with `legit` support by default, which makes whole branching routine as easy as pressing Ctrl-b.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of good answers here, however, all of them require you to do something else correctly before running `git pull`

It certainly helps to have aliases that do things like "make git push work the way it ought to, by creating a remote branch that the local is properly tracking". However, none of that helps you when you forget to use them, or went through a different workflow.

Here is a bash function that you can use to do a pull the way it ought to work, by detecting when you don't have a remote merge target configured, but there is a branch on the remote with the same name as your local branch, and setting that branch as the merge target, then pulling.

```bash
git-pulldown() {
    head="$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)"

    if [[ $(git config "branch.$head.merge") ]]; then #there's already a merge target configured, just pull as normal from there
        git pull
    else
        if [[ $(git ls-remote --heads origin $head) ]]; then #there is an upstream branch existing with the same name as our branch
            git branch --set-upstream-to origin/$head #set merge target to upstream branch with same name
            git pull
        else #fail with explanation
            echo "Branch $head has no upstream or merge target! You will likely have to push first, or manually configure it"
            return 1
        fi
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do recomend "git pull origin my_branch". I always update my local branches using it.

Answer (score 0):

use these two command to set git configuration:

```bash
git config --global --add push.default current

git config --global --add push.autoSetupRemote true
```

Answer (score -1):

There is apparently no supported way to override default options of git commands. Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16410521) to [Define git alias with the same name to shadow original command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916565/define-git-alias-with-the-same-name-to-shadow-original-command), we can override the behavior of `git push` in bash to always call `git push -u`. Put the following in your `~/.bash_profile` file, and it should be equivalent to running --set-upstream every time you push.

```sh
function do_git {
  cmd=$1
  shift
  myArgs=( "$@" )

  if [ "$cmd" == "push" ]; then
    myArgs=( "-u" "${myArgs[@]}" )
  fi
  myArgs=( "$cmd" "${myArgs[@]}" )

  $(which git) "${myArgs[@]}"
}
alias  git='do_git'
```