# How do I undo tracking a remote branch in git?

Tags: git, version-control, github

I've accidentally unhitched my master branch from tracking origin master I think. It used to be that I could run `git pull` and `git push` and it would know that I meant `git push origin master` but now it does not, and I think it's tracking a different branch because `git push origin master` works fine (everything up to date) and `git push` tells me it can't fast-forward changes.

Here's what my `git branch -a` looks like:

```
ianstormtaylor:nib Storm$ git branch -a
* master
  original
  transforms
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/sizing
  remotes/origin/transforms
```

Not sure if that `remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master` is the part that is messed up.

I think this all resulted from a `git merge origin sizing` call when i meant to do `git merge sizing` (while on master).

Anyone know what's going on and is able to help? I'd just like to get back to the default remote-tracking setup that `git clone` creates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need in you git config (do `git config -e` to edit) is the following:

```
[remote "origin"]
   fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
   url = /Users/me/test.git
[branch "master"]
   remote = origin
   merge = refs/heads/master
```

If it is there, `git push` from master, will be equivalent to `git push origin master`

The `remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master` part just says that HEAD of remote origin is master branch ( of origin) and is fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

> git branch --set-upstream my_branch origin/my_branch

Alternatively

> git push -u origin my_branch

See [Git: Why do I need to do `--set-upstream` all the time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089294/git-why-do-i-need-to-do-set-upstream-all-the-time) for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this happen a few times - and while I'm not sure of the exact cause I don't believe it's from a mistake that you've made. Rather it's simply that git pull is a *shortcut* to the most recent remote branch and it's forgotten what the most recent branch is.

Executing a `git pull origin master` usually updates the setting and resets everything.

Comment: Unfortunately `git pull origin master` doesn't seem to be reset it.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could edit the .git/config file or set the config using

```
git config branch.master.remote origin
git config branch.master.merge refs/heads/master
```

Alternatively, recreate the master branch using the `-t` (`--tracking`) option

Both should result in a section similar to *this* in your `.git/config`:

```
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```