# Update a local branch with the changes from a tracked remote branch

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, remote-branch

I have a local branch named '`my_local_branch`', which tracks a remote branch `origin/my_remote_branch`.

Now, the remote branch has been updated, and I am on the '`my_local_branch`' and want to pull in those changes. Should I just do:

```
git pull origin my_remote_branch:my_local_branch
```

Is this the correct way?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

You have set the upstream of that branch

(see:

- "[How do you make an existing git branch track a remote branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520650/how-do-you-make-an-existing-git-branch-track-a-remote-branch)" and
- "[Git: Why do I need to do `--set-upstream-to` all the time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089294/git-why-do-i-need-to-do-set-upstream-all-the-time)"
  )

```
git branch -f --track my_local_branch origin/my_remote_branch
# OR (if my_local_branch is currently checked out):
$ git branch --set-upstream-to my_local_branch origin/my_remote_branch
```

(`git branch -f --track` won't work if the branch is checked out: use the second command `git branch --set-upstream-to`  instead, or you would get "`fatal: Cannot force update the current branch.`")

That means your branch is [already configured](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) with:

```
branch.my_local_branch.remote origin
branch.my_local_branch.merge my_remote_branch
```

Git already has all the necessary information.
In that case:

```
# if you weren't already on my_local_branch branch:
git checkout my_local_branch 
# then:
git pull
```

is enough.

---

If you hadn't establish that upstream branch relationship when it came to push your '`my_local_branch`', then a simple `git push -u origin my_local_branch:my_remote_branch` would have been enough to push *and* set the upstream branch.
After that, for the subsequent pulls/pushes, `git pull` or `git push` would, again, have been enough.

Comment: The OP mentions that they're already tracking the remote branch.

Comment: @Amber hence my answer: `git pull` is enough.

Comment: The first command `git branch -f --track master origin/master` returns an error: `fatal: Cannot force update the current branch.`

Comment: @MarkKramer Yes, I have edited the answer to make it clearer the second command is to be used if the local branch is currently checked out.

Comment: You should also change it to `--set-upstream-to`, `--set-upstream` is deprecated and going to be removed.

Comment: @MarkKramer I didn't realize this answer was so old, thank you. I should have known (https://stackoverflow.com/a/40575748/6309)

Answer (score 178):

You don't use the `:` syntax - `pull` always modifies the currently checked-out branch. Thus:

```
git pull origin my_remote_branch
```

while you have `my_local_branch` checked out will do what you want.

Since you already have the tracking branch set, you don't even need to specify - you could just do...

```
git pull
```

while you have `my_local_branch` checked out, and it will update from the tracked branch.

Answer (score 8):

for somebody accidently mess the local commits.

delete local dirty branch

`git branch -D master`

then rebuild a branch from remote

`git checkout -b master origin/master`

Comment: `git branch -d master` gives me: `error: Cannot delete branch 'main' checked out at MY_BRANCH`.

Answer (score 4):

Note: I am a git novice.

When I do a "git pull", I usually see "error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:" "Please commit your changes or stash them before merge." (Because I've made minor temp changes that I don't really care about.)

I typically don't care about my changes if I am pulling from remote. I just want the latest that the team has pushed. (I have used "stash" on occasion to keep some changes.)

**So, what I do to pull the latest from remote and wipe out any of my local changes:**

*git reset --hard*               (for current branch)

or

*git reset --hard origin/master* (for going back to master)

then:

*git pull*                       (pulls the current remote files to my local)

Comment: Using `git stash` to preserve the uncommitted changes would be a wise first step if the user did care about the changes.

Answer (score 1):

As you said your local branch tracked remote upstream so we can use following command:

```
git checkout -B <new-branch> [<start-point>]

git checkout -B my_local_branch origin/my_remote_branch
```

If -B is given, `<new-branch>` is created if it doesn’t exist; otherwise, it is reset.