# How to update local branch from a different remote branch in git

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm not very good with git and I'm having a problem. I am currently on local branch `A-1` which I cloned from the remote branch `A-1`. But someone else pushed changes to the remote `develop` branch which I now need on my local `A-1`. How do I get the changes from the remote `develop` branch on to my local `A-1` branch?

I've been looking around for answers and I think I need to use `git pull` but I think I also need to specify the remote branch that I want to pull from? Otherwise I think it will just pull from the remote `A-1` branch?

From [Update a local branch with the changes from a tracked remote branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278497/update-a-local-branch-with-the-changes-from-a-tracked-remote-branch), would I need just do

`git pull origin develop`?

Comment: You can do `git rebase origin/develop` or `git merge origin/develop`, whatever suit you most. `rebase` and `merge` are powerful concepts in git, find a good book to get handy with it.

Comment: @Tarek Dakhran, thanks, can you explain a little more on what ```git merge origin/deveop``` is doing? I'll read up on it in the mean time too. Thank you. I just want to make sure that it doesn't merge my local ```A-1``` changes into ```develop```

Comment: It is opposite, it will merge `origin/develop` into your local branch. For example `git pull` is same as `git merge origin/A-1`.