# Git new branch created -- would other users be able to access the same?

Tags: git, git-branch

I created a new branch in git from my local system using the command:

```
git checkout -b branchname
```

My doubt is whether other users from their system will be able to switch to this new branch? Or do I need to push the changes to the server, then only they can also access it?

-- Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to push the branch for them to be able to fetch it.

Even if those users have a direct access to your repo and have added it as a remote, they would still need to fetch your repo in order to realize that you have created a branch.

So the act alone of creating a branch isn't enough to notify anybody.
They need to fetch, or you need at least to push to a repo from which they can fetch.

---

The [OP goose](https://stackoverflow.com/users/974680/goose) asks in the comments:

> Say if someone uses the command: git checkout my-new-branch, will they get the set of changes?

No. They would simply create a branch in their own *local* git repo.

The [documentation on Git branch](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches) has a funny expression in the top left corner:

```
Git --everything-is-local
```

**Everything is local.**

> it should be as follows: `git checkout -b new-branch` AND `git push` Is it?

You don't have to push until you are ready.
Creating the branch alone wouldn't be very interesting for others.
Wait until have have made some commits before pushing it.

But the first time you will push said new branch, set its **[upstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739376/definition-of-downstream-and-upstream/2749166#2749166)** branch immediatly:

```
git push -u origin myNewBranch
```

See "[Git: Why do I need to do `--set-upstream` all the time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089294/git-why-do-i-need-to-do-set-upstream-all-the-time)".

You only have to do once.
After that, when you want to push again (because you have made *additional* commits you want to be visible, a simple `git push` will be enough.

Comment: I dont want to push this branch to common repo, at least for now; need to make some changes before pushing. Say if someone uses the command: git checkout my-new-branch, will they get the set of changes?

Comment: Maybe you should make a new repo only for your dedicated users.

Comment: @goose no, they won't see any change or any new branch until you are pushing something. If they do a `git checkout my-new-branch`, all they are doing is creating a branch named like yours on their own local repo.

Comment: @goose as the documentation about branch mentions (top left corner of http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches): "git --everything-is-local" ;) What you are doing remains local until pushed.

Comment: Ok, it should be as follows:
git checkout -b new-branch AND 
git push
Is it?

Comment: @goose ... and push it when you want the commits you have made in them visible (fetched) by others. But creating the branch alone does not warrant a push. Creating the branch, making commits, fixes, cleanup, ... and *then* pushing the branch is ok.

Comment: @goose don't forget, on your first push, to set the upstream branch: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089294/git-why-do-i-need-to-do-set-upstream-all-the-time : `git push -u origin myNewBranch`. You do that only once. After that, a simple `git push` is enough to update your upstream branch with new commits done on your local branch.