# Git: cloning repository into new repository

Tags: git, bitbucket, repository

I am using Git (on bitbucket) and have a repository with my code. I now want to use this code and largely modify it for another project all together.

I understand that I should abstract the common components to a third library and use that but for the sake of argument, if I want to clone the current repository into a new one, is this possible without manually just copying the code and pushing to a new repo?

Comment: this isn't even a hypothetical, its quite common with customized template repos, such as a common project structure or setup used between multiple projects in the same domain.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

First clone the repository you want to work with. This step could be skipped if you want it all to happen in the folder you are already in.

```
git clone file:///path/to/repo/
```

Cloning will bring over the remotes specified in that directory. So you'll need to [remove the remotes](http://git-scm.com/book/ch2-5.html#Removing-and-Renaming-Remotes) you don't want.

```
git remote rm <remote>
```

And add the ones you do, after you have created your remote repository.

```
git remote add origin <url>
```

You will also want to [`--set-upstream-to`, or `-u`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089294/why-do-i-need-to-do-set-upstream-all-the-time/6089415#6089415) to tell git this is the remote repository this branch will update to, presuming you are on the main (or default) branch.

```
git push -u origin main
```

Then you'll need to decide which branches to keep and add to the remote. If you want to push all of them, just do `git push --mirror`. This will push all your tags and your remotes. But since we edited your remotes in an earlier step, it shouldn't be a problem.

If you only want to keep a few, you can `git push -u origin <branch>` each one you want.

Comment: Great answer. I think github and other git repo hosting platforms have switched the default branch name from master to main now. Not sure if you want to update that in your answer.

Comment: @TekkSparrow thank you, worthwhile change. I'll circle back later and maybe add a bit more clarity to the answer.

For git mailing list discussion on changing the default to match what most git cloud services have done see https://www.spinics.net/lists/git/msg393548.html 

To change the default branch name for all new repos see https://stackoverflow.com/a/63218244/2158473

Comment: note that this approach will preserve the git history from the origin repo

Comment: This appears to not preserve all the unfinished branches and their history. I could be mistaken though.

Answer (score 17):

You can simply use **`set-url`** to push your existing repository into a new repository:

1. `cd file:///path/to/repo/`
2. **`git remote set-url origin <url-of-new-repo>`**
3. `git push -u origin master`

Answer (score 4):

If you need only a particular branch of an existing repo, you can simply pull the branch into the new repo.

This will be very fast since only the commits in the branch are pulled.

E.g.

```
git init newRepo && cd newRepo
git pull <existing repo url> <branch (optional)>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can either clone the existing repo and remove the remotes, or you can copy the folder on the filesystem and change/remove the remotes in one copy.

but as your question is not too clear, here another thing that is possible:

add another remote to an existing remote (besides origin) and push to that remote.

Comment: Hi, I think that is the way to go adding a new remote and pushing to it. Thanks

Comment: depends on whether he wants another local clone or another remote repository