# Change from master to a new default branch git

Tags: git, github

Here is a scenerio:

We have a default branch `master` and we work off from this, creating branches and pushing up etc...

We have now created a `develop` branch off `master` and set this as a default development branch.

What I would like to know is, how do I now know if my `git pull` command is requesting changes from the default branch via the command line? or point to this new default branch?

What I have done:

- Since creating a new default branch `git pull` into `master` from `origin/master`

Also, any new branch, will it be from `master` or `develop`?

As you can see

```
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
PS C:\Users\dir\Documents\GitHub\repo> git log
commit 867cxx

fd956f73dc91d0022b (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/develop, origin/HEAD)
```

**update:**
this change of default branch occurred after cloning the repo.

Comment: If I understand well your question, you would like to know the branch you are working with?

Comment: For now our default branch has been Master, we have a new default branch, how do i point to this default branch? so I can work from it. If i do a git status it still says I am on master(local)

Comment: Just run `git checkout <name-of-new-branch>`.

Comment: i see - so there isn't anything specific I need to change I would just point to this branch and subsequent pull commands will get latest changes from this default branch?

Comment: If you are on Git 1.8.5+, then when you **clone** the repo, the default branch will also be returned (the one that HEAD is pointing on), if the change happened after you have cloned the repo, **I think** you need to do this manually.

Comment: Yes i am, also this changed happened after cloning the repo, what are these manual steps? so as I predicted I would have to make some form of a change but what is this change

Comment: To do, `git checkout <name-of-branch>`. I am not sure if there is any other way.

Comment: wouldn't doing this - create a local copy and when I create an upstream, it will create origin/<branch> at Master and not Development?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

As far as I know, git has no concept of a "default branch". User interfaces such as GitHub do have a default branch in the sense that when you open the web page, you see a certain branch (generally master) by default. But just speaking about git, the master branch is not special, it's just the name given to the first branch.

To create a new branch, use the `-b` flag with `checkout`, as in:

```
git checkout -b develop
```

The `git branch` command will list all of the existing branches, with a `*` next to the current branch. Any commits you make will be added to the current branch.

In your question, you mention pulling from a remote. The relevant concept is "Tracking Branches"; see the section with that name at https://git-scm.com/book/id/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches.

In short, when you do

```
git pull origin master
```

it will pull changes from the `master` branch of the `origin` repository into whichever branch is currently checked out. If you'd like, you can set up remote tracking so that git already knows where you want to pull from based on which branch you have checked out.

e.g. if you have a remote `develop-remote` branch and a local `develop-local` branch, you can set your local branch to track the remote branch via:

```
git checkout develop-local
git branch --set-upstream-to origin/develop-remote
```

Also, they might both be simply called `develop`, I just distinguished them here for clarity.

Finally, I should mention that when you do `git pull <url-of-repo>`, remote tracking is automatically established.

P.S. for more information about remotes (e.g. what does `origin` mean?), see https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes

Comment: Thanks, +1this is a good answer. I am aware of some of the concepts that you have touched upon, the confusion came from "moving" to a new default branch. I have now not changed anything and create a new branch and it has appeared under origin/develop by default. nonetheless it is a good answer!

Comment: Git does have a concept of a default branch. It’s not just a UI thing. It’s the branch you get when you `git clone` the repository (unless otherwise specified with [`--branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt--bltnamegt)). It comes from the `HEAD` symbolic ref.

Comment: @AndersKaseorg - `HEAD` refers to the currently checked out branch, correct? It changes whenever you check out a new branch.

Comment: Just as you have a local branch `refs/heads/foo`, a remote tracking branch in the local repository `refs/remotes/origin/foo`, and a branch in the remote repository `refs/heads/foo`, you also have a local `HEAD` (which, yes, refers to the currently checked out branch), a remote tracking `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` in the local repository, and a `HEAD` in the remote repository. The local `HEAD` and `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` are initialized from the remote `HEAD` on `git clone`; the local `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` is updated from the remote `HEAD` on `git remote set-head -a`.

Comment: As of git 2.8 this is no longer the case, and you can setup a default branch https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup

Comment: No, it is not true. `git config --global init.defaultBranch main` will change the name of the first created branch, as `main`, when you init a new repository. [ProGit](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell) points out that; *The “master” branch in Git is not a special branch. It is exactly like any other branch. The only reason nearly every repository has one is that the git init command creates it by default and most people don’t bother to change it.*

Answer (score 80):

With `git 2.28` you can set a global config with this command
`git config --global init.defaultBranch {branchName}`

Replace `{branchName}` with the default branch name
and now whenever you create a new git repo, the default branch will be this.

More details in my video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YccHk6QlRss

Comment: I saw this in a notice after executing `git init` (using version `2.32.0`)

Comment: Here's a blog post about it: https://github.blog/2020-07-27-highlights-from-git-2-28/

Comment: This answer is about the behavior of [`git init`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-init#Documentation/git-init.txt---initial-branchltbranch-namegt), which is not the subject of the question here. Here's an example of the question you were looking for: [Change git init default branch name](https://superuser.com/q/1419613/114579)

Answer (score 59):

When cloning a repo from GitHub, the default branch gets stored in the `HEAD` file:

```
$ cat .git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
ref: refs/remotes/origin/master
```

If the default branch is *changed* on GitHub *after* the repo has been cloned, this is not updated automatically, but can easily be fixed locally:

```
git remote set-head origin -a
```

`-a` will `set refs/remotes/<name>/HEAD according to remote`

Or explicitly to a named branch:

```
git remote set-head origin develop
```

Now, `HEAD` points to the new location:

```
$ cat .git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
ref: refs/remotes/origin/develop
```

Answer (score 3):

1. On GitHub, navigate to the main page of the repository.
2. Under your repository name, click ⚙︎Settings.
3. In the left menu, click Branches.
4. Under "Default branch", to the right of the default branch name, click.
5. Use the drop-down, then click a branch name.
6. Use the drop-down, then click a branch name.   Simple

Comment: question was about Git not GitHub, both are separate things.