# What is the difference between `main` and `master` in local repository in git?

Tags: git

It seems that github change `master` to `main` What is the difference between `main` and `master` for local repository in Git.

before `clone`, I have

```
git:(master):      # for my local repository
```

after `clone`, my `git` terminal become

```
git:(main)
```

I use `git branch`, it only show

```
*main
```

My equestion is where is my `master` for local repository.

Comment: `master` is an entirely arbitrary name for the first branch created. You can call it `main` (as GitHub does now when you create a new repo through the web UI), `default`, `bananas`, whatever. From git 2.28, you can configure this to whatever value you want for `git init` locally, too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63218244/3001761. If you still want to create a `master` branch, create it the same way you would a branch with any other name.

Comment: https://www.zdnet.com/article/github-to-replace-master-with-alternative-term-to-avoid-slavery-references/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Github changed the "master" to be "main" recently as part of the company's effort to remove unnecessary references to slavery and replace them with more inclusive terms

So, bottom line they wanted to get rid of the unpleasant term "master".

See [this article](https://www.zdnet.com/article/github-to-replace-master-with-main-starting-next-month/#:%7E:text=Starting%20next%20month%2C%20all%20new,them%20with%20more%20inclusive%20terms.)

Technically its still the same though