# How can I get my local git installation to default to main branch instead of master?

Tags: git

I use github and the built-in git installation on my macbook. Recently, github has changed its default branch from master to main. However, my local git running from terminal still defaults to master.

```
(base) Odins-MacBook-Pro:~ odin$ cd git
(base) Odins-MacBook-Pro:git odin$ mkdir hello
(base) Odins-MacBook-Pro:git odin$ cd hello
(base) Odins-MacBook-Pro:hello odin$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/odin/git/hello/.git/
(base) Odins-MacBook-Pro:hello odin$ git status
On branch master

No commits yet
```

How can I change my template/configuration so that git status returns **On branch main**?

Comment: Specifically https://stackoverflow.com/a/63218244/3001761

Comment: It did not work. I will have to check whether I have git 2.28.

Comment: Solution from stackoverflow.com/a/63218244/3001761 works with git 2.29, although the question is not exactly the same. Thank you! :)

Comment: Note the purpose of duplicates *is* to get people to answers, not necessarily to match the exact question.

Answer (score 1):

1. If needed, upgrade to git 2.28 or newer.
2. Within git, type

   command git config --global init.defaultBranch main

Thanks to jonrsharpe and maddhruv!