# What does the -u flag mean in git push -u origin master?

Tags: git, github, push

I was just wondering what does the `-u` flag mean in this command?

```
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: [git-push](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-push)

Comment: `$ git push --help` ;)

Answer (score 206, accepted):

The **-u** option does the following:
For every branch that is up to date or successfully pushed, add an upstream (tracking) reference, used by argument-less, git-pull and other commands.

So, after pushing your local branch with the **-u** option, this local branch will be automatically linked with the remote branch, and you can use git pull without any arguments.

Comment: "For every branch that is up to date or successfully pushed" - If it was pushed a remote branch is created, right? so why adding an upstream reference?

Comment: You'll be able to use `git pull` and `git push` without argument.

Comment: A late reply for @Ace 's comment: Git tends to shy away from defaults because of how many different ways there are to handle upstream and local repos and their interactions. Using `-u` adds the upstream reference by default *for that branch* so that your local copy has a tracking reference to automatically fill the [`<repository>` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt-ltrepositorygt). You can see a good way of changing the default behaviour to [auto set tracking branches in this answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6089415/270213)

Answer (score 62):

It's the same as `--set-upstream`

It's used to set origin as the upstream remote in your git config.

It may help if you don't want to manually specify the remote every time you run git push.

**Also ...**

As you're new to [stackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), take your time to read [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) section of the [Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) because sometimes you can find the answers by simply browsing [the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html).