# git - remote add origin vs remote set-url origin

Tags: git, github

I create a new repository:

```
git init
echo "# MESSAGE" >> README.md
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
```

Then I want to push my commit to the empty remote repository created on github so I have to set remote.

What is difference between using following commands ? :

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:User/UserRepo.git
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:User/UserRepo.git
```

At the end I perform push:

```
git push -u origin master
```

What happens when I call `git remote set-url origin` just after `git init`? Does `git remote set-url origin` create origin? If origin already exists after `git init` there is no difference between using those commands in my scenario, right?

Answer (score 1252):

below is used to add a new remote:

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:User/UserRepo.git
```

below is used to change the url of an existing remote repository:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:User/UserRepo.git
```

below will push your code to the master branch of the remote repository defined with `origin` and `-u` let you point your current local branch to the remote master branch:

```
git push -u origin main
```

**[Documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote)**

Comment: if I clone from A to my local and then use "git remote set-url B". will it delete the repository in A? I am trying to clone a repository from AWS code commit to GitLab

Comment: usually when I'm forking a new repo, I make a mistake and set the origin to the upstream. End up needing to correct it using the 2nd command `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:User/UserRepo.git`

Comment: `-u` *let you point your current local branch to the remote master branch* I don't get **why** I'd want to do such. I mean let's say I pulled from master, created a new featureBranch...committed my changes and then pushed my changes to origin/featureBranch and then I merged/pull that feature into my master. <— at this moment am I not done with my featureBranch? Why would I need it to point to remote master branch? Shouldn't I checkout to local/master and then pull from latest origin?

Comment: The answer is very good, except the explanation of  `-u` flag, which is, in my opinion, misleading. For explanation of `-u` flag, I would recommend to have a look at this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18867824/what-does-the-u-flag-mean-in-git-push-u-origin-master

Comment: and -u let you point your current local branch to the remote master branch: I don't understand this line... What did you mean point to?

Comment: I would be careful using that third one. Seems a bit dangerous... XD

Comment: I get the following error : error: src refspec master does not match any

Comment: @Bernie Don't forget to **add** and **commit** your work. You have to have something to **push**. We should perhaps also consider pushing to **main** rather than to **master**.

Answer (score 172):

Below will reinitialize your local repo; also clearing remote repos (ie origin):

```
git init
```

Then below, will create 'origin' if it doesn't exist:

```
git remote add origin [repo-url]
```

Else, you can use the `set-url` subcommand to edit an existing remote:

```
git remote set-url origin [repo-url]
```

Also, you can check existing remotes with

```
git remote -v
```

Comment: ```git remote set-url origin ...``` on a newly init'd repo got me the message fatal: No such remote 'origin'. ```git remote add origin ...``` worked.

Comment: @RobbVandaveer Thanks for the catch! I updated the answer for the correct use of subcommand `set-url`

Answer (score 84):

`1. git remote add origin git@github.com:User/UserRepo.git`

- This command is the second step in the command series after you initialize git into your current working repository using `git init`.
- This command simply means **"you are adding the location of your remote repository where you wish to push/pull your files to/from !!.."**
- Your remote repository could be anywhere on github, gitlab, bitbucket, etc.
- Here `origin` is an alias/alternate name for your remote repository so that you don't have to type the entire path for remote every time and henceforth you are declaring that you will use this name(origin) to refer to your remote. This name could be anything.
- To verify that the remote is set properly type : `git remote -v`

**OR** `git remote get-url origin`

`2. git remote set-url origin git@github.com:User/UserRepo.git`

This command means that if at any stage you wish to change the location of your repository(i.e if you made a mistake while adding the remote path using the `git add` command) the first time, you can easily go back & **"reset(update) your current remote repository path"** by using the above command.

`3. git push -u origin master`

This command simply pushes your files to the remote repository.Git has a concept of something known as a **"branch"**, so by default everything is pushed to the **master** branch unless explicitly specified an alternate branch.

To know about the list of all branches you have in your repository  type :`git branch`

Comment: Giving +1, for mentioning that `origin` is some sort of an alias/alternate

Answer (score 73):

- When you run `git remote add origin git@github.com:User/UserRepo.git`, then a new remote created named `origin`.
- When you run `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:User/UserRepo.git`,git searches for existing remote having name `origin` and change it's remote repository url. If git unable to find any remote having name `origin`, It raise an error `fatal: No such remote 'origin'`.

If you are going to create a new repository then use `git remote add origin git@github.com:User/UserRepo.git` to add remote.

Comment: `git init` doesn't add any origin. Only git repository will be initialize. If you clone any existing repository then it has a remote origin. Recommendation is use `git add`, after `git init` not `set-url`.

Comment: @Ram It is obvious not to call set-url after git init as it not make sense. set-url is to change and add is to add new remote.

Comment: `if you are going to create a new repository` then you can only do that using a web browser or in the command line `gh repo create USerRepo --public`

Answer (score 60):

To add a new remote, use the `git remote add` command on the terminal, in the directory your repository is stored at.

The `git remote set-url` command changes an existing remote repository URL.

So basicly, `remote add` is to add a new one, `remote set-url` is to update an existing one

Answer (score 49):

`git remote add` => **ADDS** a new remote.

`git remote set-url` => **UPDATES** existing remote.

---

1. The remote name that comes after `add` is a new remote name that did not exist prior to that command.
2. The remote name that comes after `set-url` should already exist as a remote name to your repository.

---

`git remote add myupstream someurl` => myupstream remote name did not exist now creating it with this command.

`git remote set-url upstream someurl` => upstream remote name already exist i'm just changing it's url.

---

```
git remote add myupstream https://github.com/nodejs/node => **ADD** If you don't already have upstream
git remote set-url upstream https://github.com/nodejs/node # => **UPDATE** url for upstream
```

Answer (score 47):

> **This is very simple If you have already set a remote origin url then you use `set-url` command to change that, otherwise simply use `add` command**

If you don't have a git repo already initiate one with `git init`

1. `git remote -v` Check if any remote already exists
2. If **Yes** then use `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:User/UserRepo.git` to change the origin
3. If **No** then use `git remote add origin git@github.com:User/UserRepo.git` to set new origin for your repo.
4. and finally use `git push -u origin master` to push your code to remote and add upstream (tracking) reference to your remote branch.

**NOTE:** If you use `-u` flag, its for **upstream**, it enables you to use simply `git pull` instead of `git pull origin <branch-name>` in upcoming operations.

Answer (score 25):

Try this:

```
git init  
git remote add origin your_repo.git  
git remote -v  
git status
```

Answer (score 22):

**You can not call `remote set-url origin` just after `git init`**, Because the **`git remote set-url` command will not  create origin, but it changes an existing remote repository URL**.

so the command `git remote set-url` will only work if you've either cloned the repository or manually added a remote called origin.

you can check remote with command `git remote -v` it will show remote url after name, or if this command gives error like `fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git` then the repository not exists, so you have to add origin with command `git remote add`

**1. `git remote add`**

This command is used to add a new remote, you can use this command on the terminal, in the directory of your repository.

The git remote add command takes two arguments:

1. A **remote name**, for example, origin
2. A **remote URL**, for example, https://github.com/user/repo.git

**For example:**

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/user/repo.git
```

**2.`git remote set-url`**

The git remote set-url command changes an existing remote repository URL.

The git remote set-url command takes two arguments:

1. An **existing remote name**. For example, `origin` or `upstream` are two common choices.
2. A **new URL for the remote**

For example you can change your remote's URL from SSH to HTTPS with the `git remote set-url` command.

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git
```

you can verify that the remote URL has changed, with command `git remote -v`.

**note:** "origin" is a convention not part of the command. **"origin" is the local name of the remote repository. you can use any name instead of "origin".**

For example:

```
git remote add myorigin git@github.com:user/repo.git
git remote set-url myorigin https://github.com/user/repo.git
```

References from github: [remote add](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-remote/), [remote set-url](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/)

Answer (score 9):

if you have existing project and you would like to add remote repository url then you need to do following command

```
git init
```

if you would like to add readme.md file then you can create it and add it using below command.

```
git add README.md
```

make your first commit using below command

```
git commit -m "first commit"
```

Now you completed all local repository process, now how you add remote repository url ? check below command this is for ssh url, you can change it for https.

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:user-name/repository-name.git
```

**How you push your first commit see below command** :

```
git push -u origin master
```

Answer (score 2):

We use `git remote add origin git@github.com:User/UserRepo.git` when adding a new repository to the local directory.
and we use `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:User/UserRepo.git` when changing the head to another repository.
ReadMore: https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/managing-remote-repositories