# How to remove the Git repository in VS Code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I need a help in removing the repository that I connected to my vs code.
Actually, I want to add a new repository that is a different one from the existing one.

Scenario: 'repo1' exists in the vs code. I need to add a new one i.e., 'repo2' and remove the old one 'repo1' from the vs code.

Comment: you can remove folder .git for repo1. and using terminal `git init` for new repo.

Comment: @klb please attention, if you delete .git  you will lost all of the commits and branches, If you just wanna change the repo remote do like what I say as question below

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change the URI (URL) for a remote Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432764/how-do-i-change-the-uri-url-for-a-remote-git-repository)

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is about your local git, and the the default remote name is 'origin'
In the vscode terminal/console type this command:

```
git remote set-url origin new.git.url/here
```

so, it will update your repo address.
if you want to add a new one, instead of overwriting the old one
you can simply type this commands:

```
git remote add myorigin git@github.com:User/UserRepo.git
```

then when you want to push/pull/fetch you should do like this:

```
git push -u myorigin master
```

myorigin is a custom name or alias for your new repo address.
you can call it whatever you like to.

Also, you can check existing remotes with:

```
git remote -v
```

[Check out this answer for updating existing repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432764/how-to-change-the-uri-url-for-a-remote-git-repository)

[Check out this answer for adding new repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42830557/git-remote-add-origin-vs-remote-set-url-origin)

Happy Coding friend ❤