# How to add files to an existing Github repository using Git?

Tags: git, git-branch

Suppose, I have a Github repository as `C-Basics`. In that repository, I have a branch named as `main`. And, in the `main` branch I have previously added a file `main.c`. Now if I want to add a file `first.c` to the `main` branch or wanna update the `main.c` file, which Git commands are used for this?

Comment: [This](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) is a very good ressource to learn using git ;)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git - remote add origin vs remote set-url origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42830557/git-remote-add-origin-vs-remote-set-url-origin)

Comment: I recommend searching for tutorials on basic Git commands and working with Github. Here is the tutorial from the Git book: [Recording Changes to the Repository](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository), [Working with Remotes](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes)

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should set this github repo as the repo for the new file to be uploaded.

In your cmd, go to the location of the file and type this command;

```
git remote add origin url_of_your_repo.git
```

The above command works when the local file is not a git repository.

If you want to shift a git repo to another repo;

```
git remote set-url origin url_of_your_repo.git
```