# ssh: Could not resolve hostname github: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Tags: git, github

I followed instructions here to the letter
https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh

I run the following (my username entered at `<myname>` )

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:<myname>/aws-bootstrap.git
```

I then get `fatal: remote origin already exists.`

Then I run `git push -u origin master`

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname github: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: "*Could not resolve hostname **github***" `github` must be `github.com`

Comment: Well, it looks like you already have a remote named `origin`, but it seems to have been configured with a bad hostname (`github` instead of `github.com`). You could remove the remote (`git remote rm origin`) and then re-add it using the commands you've shown in your question, or you could fix it with `git remote set-url origin ...`.

Comment: For me I discovered the `AddressFamily inet6` setting in my `~/.ssh/config`, which was for some reason preventing to connect via ssh, removing the setting or changing it to `AddressFamily any` fixed my issue. Also the use of `ssh -vvv ...` didn't really help.

Answer (score 3):

The error could be caused by a number of things, as others have mentioned though, its likely that your `origin` remote is configured incorrectly. If so, this thread has some useful context:

[git - remote add origin vs remote set-url origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42830557/git-remote-add-origin-vs-remote-set-url-origin)

I find sometimes it can be easier to manually inspect/edit the `<project dir>/.git/config` file as well incase a typo was made somewhere.

Regarding the access rights message

> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
> and the repository exists.

if your `<project dir>/.git/config` looks good, make sure your SSH private/public key are configured correctly both locally and on GitHub.

It may be helpful to print both SSH and git logs if neither of those suggestions resolve the problem:

```
$ GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vvv" $GIT_TRACE=1 git push -u origin master
```