# What does mean by -u in git command

Tags: git, command-line-interface, git-push

what is the difference between these commands:

```
git push -u origin master

git push origin master
```

Comment: `man git-push` .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18867824/what-does-the-u-flag-mean-in-git-push-u-origin-master/18867881

Answer (score 3):

In short, the `-u` parameter tells git to set upstream source for this branch. After this is done, no need to set it again, `git push origin master` is sufficent.

Comment: what do u mean upstream source ?

Comment: From [git doc](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches) : « Checking out a local branch from a remote-tracking branch automatically creates what is called a “tracking branch” (and the branch it tracks is called an “upstream branch”) »