# How to push to a new branch in Git carefully

Tags: git, github, push, git-remote

I am currently working on a team project, with many remote branches. And I cloned the project from our master's branch. Now, that I have made changes to this project locally, I would like to push it, but in-order to avoid pushing it to the projects main remote branch, I would like to create a new branch locally, and push this branch to remote.

The overall idea, is not to smash my local version of the project into the main remote project. I just need my branch to be separate.

So, I'm guessing I will first do

`git checkout -b my_new_branch`

then

`git push -u origin my_new_branch`

Will this guarantee, that my branch will not get mixed with anyone's?

Answer (score 6):

The `-u` option sets up the defaults in your repository to track `my_new_branch` on `origin`.  Thus both `push` and `pull` will, by default, use `origin` and `my_new_branch`.  Thereafter you won't need to provide those arguments.  Here is an example:

```
$ mkdir foo; cd foo; git init; touch README; git add README; git commit -m 'README'
Initialized empty Git repository in /private/tmp/foo/.git/
[master (root-commit) 03f3d46] README
 0 files changed
 create mode 100644 README

$ cd ..; git clone foo bar; cd bar
Cloning into 'bar'...
done.

$ git checkout -b my-br
Switched to a new branch 'my-br'

$ touch INSTALL; git add INSTALL; git commit -m 'INSTALL'
[my-br 627d6db] INSTALL
 0 files changed
 create mode 100644 INSTALL

$ git push -u origin my-br
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 16 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2/2), 245 bytes, done.
Total 2 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (2/2), done.
To /tmp/foo
 * [new branch]      my-br -> my-br
Branch my-br set up to track remote branch my-br from origin.

$ touch Makefile; git add Makefile; git commit -m 'Makefile'
[my-br f2390c1] Makefile
 0 files changed
 create mode 100644 Makefile

$ git push
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 16 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2/2), 255 bytes, done.
Total 2 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (2/2), done.
To /tmp/foo
   627d6db..f2390c1  my-br -> my-br
```

Notice that the final `git push` uses the proper defaults.  **The main remote repository is safe from your repository smashing it.**

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out. **You are absolutely correct.**

---

*Just to sum up all the details.*

> So, I'm guessing I will first do
>
> ```
> git checkout -b my_new_branch
> ```

That is correct approach to *create new branch* with name `my_new_branch`. You are adding all of the changes that you have made in master branch to this new branch.

> then
>
> ```
> git push -u origin my_new_branch
> ```

This then creates your *new branch on origin* which is being followed with your branch. The `-u` is the same as `--set-upstream`. More info in amazing answer for [why always git branch --set-upstream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6089415/4745695).

From now on you can use `git push` and `git pull` on remote repository as you wish with your *branch linked from local repository to remote repository*.

> Will this guarantee, that my branch will not get mixed with anyone's?

**YES**. Your master branch is absolutely safe from your push(es). And your branch is safe of mixed code, unless anyone else pushes to this branch. If this condition can be applied **it's safe to say your code will not get mixed with anyone else's code**.

Answer (score 1):

In your example your pushing a local branch to the remote repo. In this way the branch will be separated from the `master` branch.

So unless other people *voluntarily* `push` in your branch it will not get mixed with anyone's.

Comment: So, making a local remote and pushing it in the way I have stated does not cause problems to others? btw: Can we see the local branch when doing `git remote show origin` in the list of remote origins? Because I can't see mine.