# Unable to run git pull command

Tags: git, github

I have to perform migration on server which is located on Client location.
So I used to connect it using putty and run `git pull` command to specific path location in order to migrate my code.
But from today while doing same thing I am getting error as:

> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/"my repo and project
>   name"': Received HTTP code 403 from proxy after CONNECT

Attaching screenshot as well.

[image]

Comment: Please do not share images of text - put the text in a code block.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTTP 403 on GitHub pull request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29044551/http-403-on-github-pull-request)

Comment: @AD7six No, the above post didn't help me.

Comment: 1. check if mapping of your local repo exits. 2. check if your credentials are right and have valid access to it.

Answer (score 1):

If sound like your GitHub username/password provided by Git (after going through the proxy) are not correct.

Check how your GitHub credentials are provided (`git config credential.helper`), and double-check you don't have [2FA activated](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/securing-your-account-with-two-factor-authentication-2fa) (because if you do, you would need a [Personal Access Token or PAT](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line))

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have access of that repository .
Error is self explanatory.
I am afraid , you dont have the access.

To see your current git email and user name :

```
git config user.email 
git config user.name
```

You can change your email and user like :

```
git config --global user.name "a"
git config --global user.email "a@a.com"
```

Comment: Tried this, this is not helping.

Comment: The `user.name` and `user.email` settings are *not* used for authentication. They are used only when *creating new commits*, which happens locally and does not require authentication.