# Create a new branch with tracking information

Tags: git

Here's my usual workflow:

1. create new a branch: `git checkout -b foo`
2. commit some stuff
3. do a push: `git push`
4. get angry that push does not work (no upstream set)
5. reach to mouse to highlight git's recommended command (still angry)
6. push with setting upstream: `git push --set-upstream origin foo` (anger subsides)

Instead of 4. to 6., I would like to do some work when creating the new branch locally (without necessarily making my branch public yet, so **no pushing**) that kills steps 4. through 6. Is that possible?

Ideally something like `git checkout -b foo -t origin`, which informs git that I plan to track a branch of the same name in `origin`.

## What I Tried

`git checkout -b foo --set-upstream origin foo` ~> `error: unknown option 'set-upstream'`

`git checkout --track origin/foo` ~> `fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'foo' at the same time.`

`git checkout -b foo --track origin/foo` ~> `fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'foo' at the same time`

`git checkout -b foo --track` ~> `Branch foo set up to track local branch master.`

Comment: So your problem is pushing with git push origin foo ????

Comment: Yes. Too much work, breaks the flow. I want to be all `git checkout -b foo -t` (or some such thing) and be done with it. I don't want to think about whether this is my first push or not.

Comment: oook, in this case the push -u is my only option...

Comment: Besides, we need a `-u` in there or the local branch does still not track the remote one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22933955/5056219) to a slightly different topic that may help you with your workflow (not 100% sure).

> You can make this happen with less typing. First, change the way your
>   push works:
>
> ```
> git config --global push.default current
> ```
>
> This will infer the `origin my_branch` part, thus you can do:
>
> ```
> git push -u
> ```
>
> Which will both create the remote branch with the same
>   name and track it.

Actually you can even omit the `-u` and it should still work.

Comment: What?! Adding `-u` is still way too much effort! Outrageous! But since there seems to be no other alternative, I will grudgingly accept. ;)

Comment: Ha! In fact the `-u` isn't even necessary (at least on version 2.8.4). Very nice!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to set upstream on the step 1. You would be breaking the concept of `git` as a distributed version control system. You can do that with another version control system as `svn`.

Alternatively, you can use `-u` flag on `git push` to set upstream, before commit the files.

```
git branch branch-name
git push -u origin branch-name
...
git commit ...
...
git push
```

Comment: Sorry, I just edited the question to include that little detail: I do not want to push yet (maybe because I'm offline or because it's just an experiment).

Comment: if you want to set upstream on the step 1. You would be breaking the concept of git as a distributed version control system

Comment: Why would that break the concept?

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it as simple as `git checkout branch-name` without the -b. That creates a remote tracking branch associated with branch-name on your origin. Well, does for me. What am I not understanding about whats not working for you?

Comment: I added "new" to step 1. to clarify my intent, which is that I want a new branch, not one that already exists remotely.