# Do I need to git pull and merge to get the lastest update from a remote repository?

Tags: git

After I pushed my work to the feature branch of a remote repository, someone merged it to the main branch.

Since then, I haven't made any change to my local working directory and local repository and the remote repository, while others have made changes to the remote repository.

Now I want to get the latest work from the remote repository,

- is `git pull` the correct command?
- will I not need to merge, because my last commit is an ancestor of the current commit on the main branch?

Running `git pull` doesn't succeed.
The output of running `git pull` contains the following

> There is no tracking information for the current branch. Please
>   specify which branch you want to merge with. See git-pull(1) for
>   details
>
> ```
> git pull <remote> <branch>
> ```
>
> If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so
>   with:
>
> ```
> git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> core-81
> ```

What does it mean?

Thanks.

Comment: `git pull` is basically a `git fetch` followed by `git merge`. you can alway fetch the latest changes and merge it manually

Comment: Thanks and see the output of `git pull` I just added.

Comment: If your current branch doesn't track any remote branch, pulling doesn't make any sense.  You can still use `git fetch` to retrieve current versions of all upstream branches.  As pointed out above, `git pull` is essentially `git fetch` followed by `git merge`, but the merge step only makes sense if there is an upstream branch to merge into the current branch.

Comment: How do I check if my current branch track any remote branch? Do you mean a merged local feature branch will not track the main branch in remote repo?

Comment: @Tim: You already did.  Look at the output of `git pull`.

Comment: @Sven, `get fetch` quickly finished running, and doesn't seem to anything

Comment: If `git fetch` doesn't do anything, it's because there is nothing to fetch.  I agree  it could be more verbose in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You need to switch to the main branch by running

```
git checkout master
```

change master to your main branch (for example `development`).
Then run `git pull` to get the latest work from the main branch.

The most general usage of `git pull` is

```
git pull origin branch
```

Where `origin` is the remote repository, and `branch` is the remote branch to pull information from. However, you can run

```
git push -u origin branch
# or
git branch -u origin/branch branch
```

This command (`-u` stands for `--set-upstream`) will set a remote branch as a tracking for this local branch and later on you will only need to run `git pull` for this branch

Comment: (I put this same comment in on e.doroskevic's answer, but just in case, I will repeat it.) While `git pull` has a `-u` option, it simply passes it on to `git fetch`, where it means `--update-head-ok`. As [the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pull.html) says, "unless you are implementing your own Porcelain you are not supposed to use it." Note that this is quite different from `git push -u`, which you *are* supposed to use as needed.

Comment: @torek, whoops! Thank you very much, I fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

**Description**

Besically, if you haven't set up *upstream* for your branch - it will fail to `pull`; simply because `git` has no idea where to pull from

In order to pull branch you are interested in you can run

```
git pull <remote> <branch>
```

***Note:*** you can add `-u` here to set up *upstream* at this point

as `git` is suggesting to you in the output provided.

```
git branch --set-upstream-to <branch> <remote>/<branch>
```

This instruction will manually set up *upstream* for specified branch as in the above signature.

You can also set this up automatically when pushing by doing

```
git push -u <remote> <branch>
```

***Note:*** `-u` sets up an *upstream*

**EDIT 1**

*@torek*

> While git pull has a -u option, it simply passes it on to git fetch,
>   where it means --update-head-ok. As the documentation says, "unless
>   you are implementing your own Porcelain you are not supposed to use
>   it." Note that this is quite different from git push -u, which you are
>   supposed to use as needed.

**Reference**

[6089294](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089294/why-do-i-need-to-do-set-upstream-all-the-time)

Comment: While `git pull` has a `-u` option, it simply passes it on to `git fetch`, where it means `--update-head-ok`. As [the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pull.html) says, "unless you are implementing your own Porcelain you are not supposed to use it." Note that this is quite different from `git push -u`, which you *are* supposed to use as needed.

Comment: @torek strikes again :), I will edit my post to include this information