# Unknown revision or path not in the the working tree error for first push to empty remote

Tags: git

I have a local git repo with many commits. I created an empty repo in github (not initialized with any files).

```
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/bar/foo.git
$ git push -u origin master
Counting objects: 35, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Writing objects: 100% (35/35), 1.95 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 35 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (2/2), done.
remote: bar/foo
remote: fatal: ambiguous argument 'master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
remote: Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
remote: 'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
remote: master
To https://github.com/bar/foo.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

My changes are in remote and things seem to have worked fine. Still, why do I get a "fatal" error ?

> remote: fatal: ambiguous argument 'master': unknown revision or path not in the the working tree.

Comment: Did you made the first commit?

Comment: Yes, my local repo has many commits. Remote repo was newly created hence no commits at the time of push.

Comment: so it's actually two repo.you may need to pull the remote repo first.

Comment: I am sure if I clone the repo and then add my changes and then push, I won't get the fatal error. But here since I have the repo, creating a remote and pushing to it seems like a valid use case and it worked fine. The "fatal" error just seems out of place.

Comment: You have a repo then it's not compatible with the later created remote repo.The `.git` dir would be a mess,since they wouldn't merge clean and clear.So they just forbid you to make them merge.

Comment: What do you mean by "`.git` directory would be a mess"? It did not forbid me from merging. It pushed just fine despite the fatal error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143663/discussion-between-shihe-zhang-and-devnull).

Answer (score 0):

Part of the `push -u` command failed, but it shouldn't be a problem, it's a separate task. You can now try running:

```
git branch --set-upstream- master origin/master
```

or, in newer git versions:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to master origin/master
```

to set it manually. **Be sure to adjust branch names** to those you really used. The first argument here is the name of local branch that will be configured, and the second is the target that `push` will now point to by default.

So, in the example above, we're setting local `master` to push by default to `origin/master`. This is what `push -u origin master` would do. If your local repo is OK and if it has 'master' branch, then this command should simply succeed with no errors (and by the way, push-u should have as well back then).

If this command fails, you should review what branches and tracking references and upstreams etc you have configured in your local repo - something will be not right!

Maybe i.e. you don't have 'master' branch locally?

Comment: Here's [some more information](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089294/why-do-i-need-to-do-set-upstream-all-the-time)

Comment: @Cœur: well, ok, just do what the error says, I'll update the answer in the meantime :)