# git branch not showing as ahead of origin after commit

Tags: git, version-control, git-branch

I have a git feature branch which I created from the development branch with:

`git checkout -b CRM-feature-branch develop`

I then pushed this to he remote with:

`git push origin HEAD`

When I commit to this branch locally and do a `git status` it doesn't show my branch is ahead.

Is this because I created the branch on the origin with `git push origin HEAD` and not `git push origin -u CRM-feature-branch`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in short: **yes**. If you don't use `--set-upstream` (or `-u` in short), then your local git repository does not know the "remote counterpart" for the branch you are on. You can still fix this using

```
git push -u origin CRM-feature-branch
```

or

```
git branch --set-upstream CRM-feature-branch origin/CRM-feature-branch
```

for further reading: [Why do I need to do `--set-upstream` all the time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6089294/2082964)

Comment: It's strange that it _does_ push to the repo and create a new branch on the origin even when I don't specify the `-u` flag though.