# Why do I need to do `--set-upstream-to` all the time when pulling?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-pull

I typically have to clone remote branches that I do not have in my git repo (ex. from coworkers)

While there is an easy setting for `git push` (see [Why do I need to do `--set-upstream` all the time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089294/why-do-i-need-to-do-set-upstream-all-the-time))
I haven’t found the same to be true for git pull.

Right now my workflow is:

- oh I have to pull `branch123` from `projectABC` from github
- `cd projectABC && git checkout -b branch123`
- `git pull`

Alas I am greeted with:

> There is no tracking information for the current branch. Please
>   specify which branch you want to merge with. See git-pull(1) for
>   details.
>
> ```
> git pull <remote> <branch>
> ```
>
> If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so
>   with:
>
> ```
> git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> branch123
> ```

How can I make this easier?

Comment: What do you mean by “all the time”?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I was mirroring the other SO post here, I meant every time I want to pull a new branch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the `-b`-flag for checkout you actually create a new local branch, not linked to any remote branch. The first time you push your new branch you can link it to the new remote branch by doing `git push -u`. If you are checking out an existing branch, just drop the `-b`.

Comment: I wasn't aware, will try!

Answer (score 2):

If you are checking out a branch that only exists as `origin/branchName` (so `git branch -l` does not list `branchName` without the `origin`) like so:

```
git checkout branchName
```

You will create a new local branch that tracks `origin/branchName` automatically. Git should also inform you of this:

```
Branch branchName set up to track remote branch branchName from origin.
Switched to a new branch 'branchName'
```

When you use the `-b` flag, you'll need to add the `-t` flag as well to set up the tracking in one go:

```
git checkout -b branchName -t origin/branchName
```

This command is really only useful if you want your local branch to have a different name from the one on `origin`. In the simple case, just leave out the `-b`.

Alternatively, you can use the `-u` argument as mentioned [in @Tobb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52662813/256138) on your first push. This essentially does the same automagic mapping to the remote's branch of the same name that the plain `git checkout` does.

Comment: I wasn't aware, will try!

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you do:

```
git branch -u %remotename%/%branchname%
```

Replace %remotename% with your remote name which you set up, which mostly is called "origin". Replace %branchname% with the remote branch name.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with:

- oh I have to pull branch123 from projectABC from github
- cd projectABC && git checkout -b branch123
- git track <= this is the interesting bit
- git pull

With the following alias in my .gitconfig

```
  track = "!f(){ branch=$(git name-rev --name-only HEAD); cmd=\"git branch --set-upstream-to ${1:-origin}/${2:-$branch} $branch\"; $cmd; }; f"
```

Credit: https://andre.arko.net/2012/05/29/track-remote-git-branches-with-ease/