# How to set default upstream for a new branch in git?

Tags: git

I'd like to set the default upstream branch of any branch I create locally to be `origin/main`.

This is mainly for `pull --rebase`, since we never push to remote (only through a code review process).

Right now I achieve this by:

```
$ git checkout -b some-new-branch-name
$ git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/main
```

It's OK (I have a Bash alias to do that for me), but I was wondering whether I can set git's config to do that automatically.

So far I looked through the `git-config` documentation and StackOverflow questions but haven't found a solution.

Is this possible?

Comment: Even if you can't automate it, you can streamline it by setting the upstream as part of the branch creation - `git checkout -b some-new-branch-name --track origin/master`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I need to do \`--set-upstream\` all the time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089294/why-do-i-need-to-do-set-upstream-all-the-time)

Answer (score 5):

You can set the `branch.autoSetupMerge` option to `true` to have Git automatically enable `--track` (which is equivalent to setting the upstream) for branches that are created from remote refs.

However, `true` is actually the default value for this setting - the reason you're likely not seeing its effect is because you're actually creating branches that start from the *local* copy of `main`.

If you create your branches with something like:

```
git checkout -b new-branch-name origin/main`
```

Then then would automatically track `origin/main`.

Comment: Thanks, that could be a solution but it means that I now have to type `git checkout -b new-branch-name origin/whatever-base-branch-I-want` instead of the simple `git checkout -b new-branch-name` I have now. Not much of an improvement.

BTW for a couple of our repositories the "main" branch has a different name, it would be nice if I could just tell git "track whatever the original branch tracked".

Answer (score 1):

You could use a post-checkout hook to set the upstream branch https://schacon.github.io/git/githooks.html

Comment: Thanks. It looks promising. I'm looking at ways to implement this.