# Can't track origin/master

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

I can't add origin/master as tracking branch to the local master branch

```
git checkout --track origin/master
fatal: 'origin/master' is not a commit and a branch 'master' cannot be created from it
```

My fork has some commits in it already. Remote(fork) also has 1 commit with README in it. What can be the problem?

Edit: after running `git fetch origin`, the error message changes:

```
git checkout --track origin/master
fatal: A branch named 'master' already exists.
```

Comment: @eftshift0 no, git branch -r is empty

Comment: That can't be good if this is a fork... unless you forked from an empty repo.

Comment: @eftshift0 fetched origin and now it's listed, but still can't track. git checkout --track origin/master
fatal: A branch named 'master' already exists.

Comment: Is master already tracking origin/master? `git branch -vv` If not, `git checkout master` then `git branch -u origin master`

Comment: @EncryptedWatermelon git branch -u origin master
error: the requested upstream branch 'origin' does not exist
hint: 
hint: If you are planning on basing your work on an upstream
hint: branch that already exists at the remote, you may need to
hint: run "git fetch" to retrieve it.
hint: 
hint: If you are planning to push out a new local branch that
hint: will track its remote counterpart, you may want to use
hint: "git push -u" to set the upstream config as you push.

Comment: @EncryptedWatermelon but i've already fetched remote, and even tried again to fetch and branch -u

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear to me how you created your local repository in the first place, but I suspect you did this:

```
mkdir new-repo
cd new-repo
git init
```

and then created some files and `git add`ed them and committed the result.  This would leave you with a new repository with just one commit in it, and no `origin` remote, so you would then have had to run:

```
git remote add origin ssh://git@github.com/your/repo.git
```

or similar.

It's not clear to me how you created `your/repo.git` (or whatever its path may be) on GitHub, but I suspect you used the "create a new repository with a README file in it" button.

If all of these "suspects" are correct, this explains everything.  Your initial error:

> ```
> fatal: 'origin/master' is not a commit and ...
> ```

occurred because you had not yet connected your Git to GitHub's Git that holds the repository you created at GitHub.

You then ran `git fetch origin`, which had your Git connect to their Git and obtain *their* (single) commit containing a README file.  Your Git copied their commit into your repository.  Your Git then created your own `origin/master` remote-tracking name, to remember the hash ID of their (single) commit.

You now have *two* initial (created-from-nothing) commits, which Git calls *root* commits.  If we draw a diagram of your repository, it might look like this:

```
A   <-- master

B   <-- origin/master
```

Your first commit, represented here as `A`—whatever its actual hash ID might be—holds the files you committed.  Your branch name `master` identifies this one commit.

*Their* first commit, represented here as `B`, holds the files they committed.  Your remote-tracking name `origin/master` identifies this one commit.

You now ask your Git to create a new branch name `master` pointing to commit `B`, using your `origin/master`, via the failing command:

> ```
> git checkout --track origin/master
> fatal: A branch named 'master' already exists.
> ```

The reason for the error message is clear: you already have a branch name `master`, pointing to existing commit `A`; it's not possible to create a new but identical branch name `master` pointing to existing commit `B`.

#### What to do about this

You have a number of options for proceeding from here.  They mostly involve creating a new commit `C`.

You can join your history (your one lone commit) to their history (their one lone commit) by using `git merge`.  To do so, you will need the `--allow-unrelated-histories` option, unless your version of Git is old enough not to *have* the option.  A Git that old just assumes that `--allow-unrelated-histories` should always be implied.

If their lone commit `B` is autogenerated, merging histories like this is a bit silly.  It would make more sense to just throw out their commit entirely.  Take anything you find useful from their commit `B` and make your own new regular commit `C`:

```
A <-C   <-- master

B   <-- origin/master
```

Your new commit `C` will point only to your existing `A`.  You can now force them to throw away their commit `B`, sending them your new `C`.

Or, you can go ahead and merge the two commits:

```
A
 \
  C   <-- master
 /
B   <-- origin/master
```

You can now send them commit `C` and ask them to make their `master` remember `C`, which remembers both `A` and `B`.

To send them new commit `C` (which will bring with it `A`, and point back to `A`, and maybe also to `B` depending on how you made `C`), use `git push origin master`.  This sends `C` (and `A`) and ends with a polite request that they please, if they would, make their name `master` point to `C`.  If you deliberately *threw out* `B`, by not making a merge, you'll need to upgrade the polite request to a command: `git push --force origin master`.

When this is all done, *their* `master` will also point to (their copy of the now-shared) commit `C`.  Your Git will update your own `origin/master` to remember that their `master` remembers `C`, and you'll both agree that `C` is the last commit of your and their branches, both of which are named `master`.

Meanwhile, your own `master` won't have `origin/master` set as its *upstream*.  There's no reason it *must* be, but if you'd like it to be—see [Why do I need to do `--set-upstream` all the time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6089294/1256452)—you can use `git branch --set-upstream-to`, or you can combine your `git push` with the `-u` option:

```
git push -u origin master
```

or:

```
git push --force -u origin master
```

(with the `--force` option only required when you're telling them: *forget about your commit `B`, it's useless, use my `C` instead—which is not required if your `C` points back to `B`).

Instead of either merge *or* override, you have yet more options, which also create a new commit `C`.  You can:

- rebase your `A` on their `B`, using `git rebase -i --root`, or
- copy your `A` to a new commit `C` that sits atop their `B`, on a new branch *not* named `master`.

The rebase works by doing the copy, then abandoning your original `A` in favor of this new `C`:

```
A   [abandoned / lost - will eventually be garbage collected]

B   <-- origin/master
 \
  C   <-- master
```

Or:

```
A   <-- master

B   <-- origin/master
 \
  C   <-- newbranch
```

You can then rename your `master`, e.g., to `old-master` and rename `newbranch` to `master`:

```
A   <-- old-master

B   <-- origin/master
 \
  C   <-- master
```

In the end, you can now `git push -u origin master` to send them commit `C` (this time without sending `A` at all) and ask them to set their `master` to point to new commit `C`.

#### How to make sense of all of this

Go back and re-examine all of the earlier diagrams and think about things like this:

- What matters to Git are the *commits*, which never change (but can be abandoned and eventually tossed entirely).
- *Names*, like `master` and `origin/master`, merely serve to find the *last* commit in some sequence of commits.
- The hash ID of any commit—you'll see these big ugly hash IDs in `git log` output—is how Git finds a commit.  By storing the *last* hash ID in each name, Git can find all the last ones.  Each commit itself stores the big ugly hash ID of its immediate predecessor: commit `C` points back to commit `A`, or commit `B`, or both, depending on how we make it.

It's the *commits* that actually matter.  Git gives you the names, because names mean something to humans (who can't remember big ugly hash IDs), and then uses the names to *find* the commits.  Those commits that Git can find by name, store hash IDs of earlier commits.  Those earlier commits store hash IDs of even-earlier commits, and so on.  The `git log` command just starts at the current *end* and works backwards, showing you commits as it goes.

Answer (score 1):

- Get latest version
  `git fetch -apt`
- Check if your remote is correct with
  `git remote -v`
  If the remote is not correct please do `git remote add origin <your repo>`
- Save your current master branch with a tag:
  `git tag -l old-master`
- Remove your local master (you already saved it with the tag)
  `git branch -D master`
- Get the latest remote master
  `git switch -c <branch> --track <remote>/<branch>`

Answer (score 0):

We were having this exact error in a Windows machine running gitbash on a folder   synced with google drive.

**It was caused by having the feature "Enable experimental built-in file system monitor" enabled.**

After uninstalling and reinstalling gitbash with this feature disabled it was fixed.

[image]