# What is the git command equivalent for this Visual Studio check box?

Tags: git, visual-studio

What is the git command equivalent of this Visual Studio check box?

I though it is `git checkout --track` but the label suggests domething diffrent.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `git branch -u origin/master` after running `git checkout -b`

The full command is `git branch --set-upstream-to origin/master`.

See also:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/6089415/736079

Comment: But in the UI I posted, the textbox label says "origin/master" Did you mean git branch --set-upstream-to origin/master?

Comment: I thought cop/paste from SO is my secret only ;)

Answer (score -1):

If I am understanding it correctly, you are trying to checkout a branch other than master. For that the command should be - `git checkout [branchName]`

Comment: this is the UI that creates a branch. I think you are misunderestanding the checkbox I pointed at.

Comment: Okay. I may not be following what you are trying to achieve? I thought you are trying to checkout a branch from git and you are looking for a command. Please let me know if my understanding is not correct. Thanks

Comment: The UI I posted comes from Visual Studio 2019 Git UI. That particular VS UI dialog creates a new branch. I am trying to deeper underestand what the UI does, bu learning its commandline equivalent.

Comment: okay followed. so for this your git command should be git checkout --track origin/my_branch

Comment: Actually, I think it relates to `git branch --set-upstream-to`