# Skip --set-upstream doing git push

Tags: javascript, typescript, git

I'm really annoyed I have to do

```
`git push --set-upstream origin <my_branch>`
```

every time for new git branch. Is there any way I can skip it? I found this
https://github.com/nvbn/thefuck

but I'm looking for solution that skip `push --set-upstream`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I need to do \`--set-upstream\` all the time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089294/why-do-i-need-to-do-set-upstream-all-the-time)

Comment: Make yourself an alias, `git pushnew` for instance, that does `git push -u origin HEAD`.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you don't want to *skip* it per se, you still want to set upstream but without so much hustle, right? In that case, you can use a shortcut:

```
git push -u origin <my_branch>
```

Comment: what shortcut? it's still `-u`