# Your configuration specifies to merge with the ref 'refs/heads/Branch' from the remote, but no such ref was fetched

Tags: git

This is a basic question, but I'm suffering from this.
I cannot pull anything from a shared github repo to my branch, Pabasara.

```
D:\Academic\L2S2\IN 2900 - Industry Based Project\rs-client>git status
On branch Pabasara
nothing to commit, working tree clean
 

D:\Academic\L2S2\IN 2900 - Industry Based Project\rs-client>git branch
* Pabasara
  dev

D:\Academic\L2S2\IN 2900 - Industry Based Project\rs-client>git pull
Your configuration specifies to merge with the ref 'refs/heads/Pabasara'
from the remote, but no such ref was fetched.
```

What should I do?

Comment: which origin branch you want to pull from ? dev also? or there's actually another branch there called `Pabasara` too ?

Comment: There are two branches called dev and Pabasara. I want to pull from dev to Pabasara

Answer (score 3):

You're clearly new to Git, and as such, I recommend *avoiding* the `git pull` command.  The reason for this is straightforward: `git pull` is a *convenience* command that runs *two separate Git commands for you*.  But you don't yet know how to operate the two separate Git commands.  Don't use the power tool until you know how to work the two hand tools first, and where sharp blades might stick out during the operation.  (Not everyone agrees with this philosophy, but I think you should know how each manual tool works, at a pretty good level, before you start using the automatic and powered ones.)

#### Pull = fetch + merge: you should run fetch, then merge

Generally, running `git pull` is like first running `git fetch`, then running `git merge`.  But there are a lot of exceptions to this rule, and things can get very complicated.  See my long answer to [Git fetch and git pull relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72482795/1256452) for much more about this.  To *avoid all the complications*, especailly when you're new to Git, simply:

1. Run `git fetch` or `git fetch origin`: this obtains, from some other Git software working with some other Git repository, all the commits that *they* have, that *you don't have yet*.  After the `git fetch` finishes, you now have all of their commits, *plus* any commits of your own that you have made.
2. (Optional.)  Using the output from `git fetch`, or even ignoring the output of `git fetch`, use `git log` to *inspect* the new commits: the commits they have that you didn't, but do now.

   For instance, in this particular case, you might run:

   ```
   git log Pabasara..origin/dev
   ```
3. Run the second command of your choice: `git merge` or `git rebase`.  Depending on how you configure `git pull`, you get to choose which second command `git pull` runs after it runs `git fetch`.  But before you start doing that, just *manually* run the command you prefer here.

You'll need to learn just what both `git merge` and `git rebase` do, including what to do when they *fail partway through*.  This happens whether you run them yourself, manually, or have `git pull` run them.  The recovery process is different for `git merge` vs `git rebase`, so you need to know *which one* `git pull` actually ran.  If you run it yourself for now, you'll know.

There's one thing that's especially weird here, that you just have to memorize.

When you use `git fetch`, your Git calls up the other Git software over at `origin` and gets their commits, and then updates your *remote-tracking names*.  Use `git branch -r` to see your remote-tracking names: they will look like `origin/master` or `origin/main`, `origin/dev`, and so on.  That is, they all have `origin/` in front of them.  This is *your Git's memory* of *their Git's branches* (where by "your Git" I mean *your software working in your repository*, and by "their Git" I mean *their software working in their repository* ).

To merge *their latest `dev`* into *your* `Pabasara`, then, you obviously need:

```
git merge origin/dev
```

which is the correct command to use here.  Running `git merge dev` is wrong because it means to merge *your* `dev`; that's *your* `dev` and you want *their* `dev` here, as just updated by your earlier `git fetch`.

But when you use `git pull`, you supply the name of *their* branch: `git pull origin dev`.  So instead of `origin/dev` it's now `origin dev`, with a space.  The reason why is one of those messy historical items I describe in my long answer to the linked question.  This weirdness, where sometimes you use `origin/dev` and in *one special case only* (namely `git pull`) you use `origin dev` instead, is something you just have to memorize—or you can avoid `git pull` and now you don't have to memorize this!

Answer (score 1):

To pull locally `dev` into `Pabasara` you should use:
`git checkout Pabasara` to make sure you are there, then **`git merge dev`**

Answer (score 1):

Branch "Pabasara" was deleted on server.
This was the error reason in my case.

To sync branches with server run:

```
git checkout dev
git remote prune origin
```

This command removed local branch "Pabasara" in my case.