# gitolite: error: src refspec master does not match any

Tags: gitolite

I have created an empty git repository by use of gitolite and cloned it to my laptop. Usually, I can add files to it on my laptop on and push them to the repo but now an error occurs:

```
user@laptop Myproject % git clone newergit:Repo-Myrepo
Cloning into 'Repo-Myrepo'...
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
user@laptop Myproject % cd Repo-Myrepo
user@laptop Repo-Myrepo % vi test.txt
user@laptop Repo-Myrepo % git add test.txt 
user@laptop Repo-Myrepo % git commit -m "add test file to repo"
[main (root-commit) 27aa970] add test file to repo
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 test.txt
user@laptop Repo-Myrepo % git push origin master
error: src refspec master does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'newergit:Repo-Myrepo'
```

This used to work in the past but newly I am experiencing this error and don't know how to proceed?

Comment: Run a `git status` and a `git branch -al` and add it?   You may find that the default branch is now `main` not `master`

Comment: Unfortunately, git branch -al did not resolve the problem - I obtain the same error message as before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Unfortunately, `git branch -al` did not resolve the problem

A `git branch -avv` is only there to list the local and remote branches, for you to understand which branch was created (locally by your git commit and remotely by Gitolite)

If you [use Git 2.37+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72401899/6309), you can activate the

```
git config --global push.autoSetupRemote true
```

From there, a simple `git push` (without any additional parameter) should be enough. It will pick the right branch name (the current one) and push it to the remote with remote tracking.

Comment: I have tried ```git config --global push.autoSetupRemote true``` but the same error message appears: ```user@laptop Repo-Myrepo % git push origin master
error: src refspec master does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'newergit:Repo-Myrepo'```

Comment: @jos The idea with that configuration is to then just use `git push`. If, however, the error message persists, you should edit your question with the output of `git status` and `git branch -avv`.

Comment: Great, I have executed ```git push``` instead of git ```git push origin master``` and now it works. Thank you, you have saved my day!

Comment: @jos Great, well done! A `git push` will pick up the current branch.