# Can I disable git pull?

Tags: git

Is there any way to disable `git pull`?

I'd like to either make it not work or not do anything, so that, when typing it by mistake, it won't cause me problems.

Comment: What do you mean to type instead? Are you sure you're not just going to mistakenly type whatever the new command to pull is?

Comment: Is your operating system Linux?

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski Mac OS X, though I'd prefer a solution that relies solely on git capabilities.

Comment: @user2357112 `git fetch`, which does not do the same thing as `git pull`.

Comment: you know git pull is git fetch + git merge, right?

Comment: Also Git asks for password(if you've not cached it)... so just typing command will do nothing ....

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski Yes, so?

Comment: @Nemesis `credentials.helper = cache` kind of defeats that, sadly.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral so you just want to avoid accidentally running `git pull`, is that correct?

Comment: @Cupcake Yes. Wasn't that clear in the question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you are on OSX, you can write a function to check if you typed git pull.

If so, it will print a message, otherwise it will call git with the parameters.

Example:

```
git() { if [[ $@ == "pull" ]]; then command echo "Cannot pull!"; else command git "$@"; fi; }
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way, if you've got root permissions, would be to:

```
$ sudo chmod 000 /usr/lib/git-core/git-pull
```

… or wherever the file is in your FS. Then:

```
$ git pull
fatal: cannot exec 'git-pull': Permission denied
$
```

Alternatively, you could replace it with something along the lines of

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "git-pull is disabled"
exit 1
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess the problems you refer to are merge conflicts that may happen if your local branch diverged from the remote. In that case, try setting `pull.ff` option in git config, like that:

```
[pull]
    ff = only
```

This will tell git to only do fast-forward merges, which are guaranteed to not result in conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

It is not directly possible in git, because git aliases are not allowed to override built-in commands.

However, you can create a bash function and alias that proxies your git command and modifies it. [Steve Bennett gives a great example in this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916565/define-git-alias-with-the-same-name-to-shadow-original-command#answer-16410521)