# Is it possible to make git clone recursive by default?

Tags: git

Is it possible to make `git clone` do `git clone --recursive` by default?

Comment: @TylerH: Almost, but the answer here is worth saving, and it wouldn't quite fit there.

Comment: @einpoklum fair point, but questions closed as duplicates are not deleted by the Roomba, as they act as useful signposts.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, it is not possible, see:

[Is it possible to override git command by git alias?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538774/is-it-possible-to-override-git-command-by-git-alias)

However, you can define a similar instead:

```
git config --global alias.cloner "clone --recursive"
```

then

```
git cloner http://localhost/yyy.git
```

Comment: Interesting. I had ``alias glone="git clone --recursive"`` in my bashrc file but I think I prefer this. I didn't know you could alias git commands. Thank you.

Comment: @Sahand I believe that's not possible, actually: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916565/#comment6812824_5916565