# how to make git ignore ignores in .gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore, git-status

I have a Git repository that contains a `.gitignore` file, which lists a few files (that are created during the build) to be ignored.

```
$ cat .gitignore
foo
$ ls
bar
$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
$ touch foo
$ ls
bar foo
$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
$
```

In a specific clone of that repository, I *do* want to see the files listed in `.gitignore`.

This can be done with the `--ignored` option to `git status`:

```
$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
$ git status --ignored
On branch master
Ignored files:
  (use "git add -f <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    foo

nothing to commit, working directory clean
$
```

Nice. My question is: how can I make this permanent for a **given** repository, so that I do not have to remember to add the `--ignored` flag?

```
$ git status
On branch master
Ignored files:
  (use "git add -f <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    foo

nothing to commit, working directory clean
$
```

I'm sure there is some `git config`uration that allows me to configure my clone to ignore the contents of `.gitignore`...

Also, I don't want to have this option for *all* repositories; only for a select few.

Comment: That's a lot of *ignore*'s in one title `:)`

Comment: @Jubobs http://i3.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/000/001/122/xzibit-happy.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

none of the proposed solutions did what i actually wanted.

however, @Jubobs suggestion of a wrapper function finally gave me the idea of how to actually do it.

### outline

- *flag* a given repository for the change, preferrably using the *git way*. this can be accomplished using `git config` and some *user defined* variable
- why stop with adding a single option (`--ignored`) to a single command (`status`)?
  it would be nice if we could pass default arguments for each git command,

### implementation

so i ended up with the following little snippet, to be sourced at startup:

```
git() {
  local GIT=$(which git)
  case "x$1" in
    x|xconfig)
      ${GIT} "$@"
    ;;
    *)
      ${GIT} $1 $(${GIT} config --get $1.options) "${@:2}"
    ;;
  esac
}
```

so in my special repository, i simply do:

```
$ git config --add status.options "--ignored"
```

after that, running the following command in this repo will show me even ignored files, while other repositories will behave as usual.

```
$ git status
```

### discussion

- you can add your personal options to any *git command* by creating a config-option named `${cmd}.options`.
  e.g. if you prefer to *decorate* your `git log` output, simply do:

  ```
  $ git config log.options "--decorate"
  ```
- the script excludes the `config` subcommand for safety reasons. this should prevent shooting yourself in the knee with something like:

  ```
  $ git config add config.options --fuzz
  ```
- finally, it uses some [bashisms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29#Portability) (namely `${@:2}`) to allow for arguments containing whitespace; if your shell is not `bash`, take care...

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is create an alias (let's call it `istatus`) for `$ git status` command.

```
$  git istatus
On branch master
Ignored files:
  (use "git add -f <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    foo

nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

How to do it is [described here](http://githowto.com/aliases) and even there's [a similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553786/how-do-i-alias-commands-in-git).

**TL;DR:** Basically you just need to add lines to ~/.gitconfig:

```
[alias]
    istatus = status --ignored
```

Comment: hmm, i'm really looking for a solution that does not require *me to remember* anything special about the given repository.

Comment: Look at the accepted answer to [this question regarding shadowing aliases on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916565/define-git-alias-with-the-same-name-to-shadow-original-command)

Comment: You're missing a "d" at the end; it should be `git status --ignored`.

Answer (score 1):

### Not possible (yet)

Git (at least v2.1 and older) does *not* allow you to configure `git status` to also list ignored files by default.

What Git does allow you to do, though, is modify the behavior of `git status` with respect to untracked file via the [`status.showUntrackedFiles`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html) option.

Perhaps a future version of Git will feature a "`status.showIgnoredFiles`" option...

### So, what can you do?

#### 1 - Define a alias locally

The obvious and probably best thing to do would be, as suggested by Kleskowy in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25909766/2541573), to define an alias local to your repository:

```
git config alias.istatus "status --ignored"
```

Then, running `git istatus` instead of `git status` in the repository in question would also list ignored files.

#### 2 - Define a small wrapper around `git`

**Caveat**: The following approach applies at the user level, not at the repository level.

Alternatively, if you're not averse to having a small wrapper around `git`, you can define the following, which automatically uses the `--ignored` flag when `git status` is run:

```
git() {
    if [[ ($1 == "status") ]]; then
        command git status --ignored "${@:2}";
    else
        command git "$@";
    fi;
}
```

Put those lines in your `.<shell>rc` file and source the latter.

Here is the result of a test (in `bash`) of that wrapper in one of my repositories:

[image]

Note that ignored files also get listed, even though the `--ignored` flag is not used explicitly.

### Conclusion

Unless someone can think of a better approach, what you're asking is essentially a feature request for Git; therefore, I'm not sure your question has its place here...

Comment: this is nice if you want that behaviour for *all* repositories. i'm really interested in a solution that is configurable *per-repo*.