# Auto ignore date during git rebase

Tags: git, config, rebase

I know that for not changing the commit dates, we can use `git rebase --ignore-date` but i want this to be my default behaviour for every rebase I do.

Is there any way to set it in git configs?
Something like

```
git config --global rebase.ignoreDate true
```

I don't want to make any alises, is there any sophisticated solution for this?

Comment: Making an alias *is* the sophisticated solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering [`t3436-rebase-more-options.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/t/t3436-rebase-more-options.sh#L167-L173), there is no configuration or environment variable which would set `--ignore-date` by default for a rebase.

If making an alias does not work for your (because you want to type only git rebase, and [you cannot override a builtin command by an alias](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26937650/6309)), you might consider a git wrapper ([as in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52132752/6309))

The wrapper script can detect a `rebase` command, add the missing `--ignore-dated` option, and call the actual git executable with all the parameters initially passed to the wrapper.