# Create an alias with more than 1 command as the alias name

Tags: bash, git, github

I want to create an alias that is composed of 2 commands. Could not find anything online as most questions are about an alias that **equals** to 2 commands, eg:

```
alias command="command1 && command2"
```

What I want:

```
alias git push="git add . && git commit -m 'auto ups' && git push"
```

Why using this instead of naming my alias *gp* (or whatever 1 worded alias)

1. I want to keep the same *git push* experience
2. Want to learn about bash

Is that possible?

Comment: see: `PAGER='less +/^\ *aliases' man bash`

Comment: Not with shell aliases, but with [Git aliases](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases); though you can't overwrite an existing Git command, I believe.

Comment: What is a _git push experience_? Sounds like the name of a novel joy ride or entertainment park. BTW if you want a command to **unconditionally** run two commands in a row, it is `alias foo=command1;command2`. Your approach executes _command2_ only if _command1_ returns a exit-code 0.

Comment: `alias git push =` does not work, since an alias name can not contain spaces. Naming it `git_push` or `git.push` would work.

Comment: @user1934428 "git push experience" refers to not having to change the command to something else. Also, you are right for the && but in this context the point is simply to run whatever chain of command you want with a 2 word alias command..

Comment: Then you can achieve this of course with the approach given by _VonC_ in his answer. I surely don't want to recommend redefining a standard command, because you always have to keep in mind, that your version of the command is behaving differently from what everyone expects. This could bite you someday....

Comment: The way I'd put it is that you've given yourself a totally different "experience": the standard "experience" is that you add, then commit. At some other time, you push. You don't do all three at once, and when you get better at Git, you won't *want* to do all three at once. Still, you *can* do this sort of thing, it's just harder than using a bash or Git alias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [illustrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52132752/6309), you would need to define a `git` wrapper.
It should be set in your `$PATH` *before* the `/usr/local/bin/git` itself.
Or you can reference that script through an `alias git=git-wrapper` in  your `~/.bash_profile`.

In that wrapper, on `push`, you can then call a script which would chain any `git` command you need.