# Is it possible to clone git config from remote location?

Tags: git

I have a bare repo on remote location with some configs I'd like to share with everyone who clones it. Is it possible? Every time I clone, it seems to revert everything in `.git/config` to defaults and just add information about remote repo.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I confirm a local config (the one within `.git/config`) is never shared amongst repo
(for various security reasons, like, for instance,:

- a git alias which would define some commands only valid in your particular environment
  (or <del>git commands themselves</del>: *no*, as [Jan Hudec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/201725/jan-hudec) comments, and as detailed in the question "[Is it possible to override git command by git alias?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538774/is-it-possible-to-override-git-command-by-git-alias)")
- some github directive ([`github.token`](http://help.github.com/set-your-user-name-email-and-github-token/)) supposed to be secret and incorrectly entered in the local config instead of the global one
- personal config like `user.name` and `user.email` (which can be set on a local level if those differs from other repos): that wouldn't make sense to propagate my name and email when other clone my repo.
- ...
  ).

The closest way to do that would be to version an actual file with the config in it, and invite users to copy it in their `.git/config` file

Comment: Actually aliases are not allowed to redefine existing commands. However your argument still stands; config indeed still gives too much control to be safe to distribute automatically.

Comment: @Jan: good point, I have included your comment in the answer, as well as a link to an older SO question which should have taught me that fact a year ago ;)

Comment: What about the config file of a "bare repository", i.e. generally a remote central repository? (more specifically I'm looking for the github default config settings)

Comment: @KIaze One could save-and-retrieve the remote configs from.  special dedicated branch with some special programs for convenience. http://stackoverflow.com/a/21057383/94687

Answer (score 1):

A .gitconfig file checked in is possible, but no great from a security perspective

[Storing git config as part of the repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18329621/storing-git-config-as-part-of-the-repository)

Im still trying to figure it out, but I would also like to add an 'upstream' remote , and have that saved in the origin's repo... so users don't need to do git remote add on every clone...