# how to set git core.autocrlf for a submodule

Tags: git, configuration, git-submodules, core.autocrlf

Is it possible to configure core.autocrlf=false for a specific submodule?
I do not have push access for the submodule, so I need to set it from outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not put --global should be enough

```
git config core.autocrlf  false
```

But if the question is how do do it and share it in your repo to be available for git clone, you can't. But you can use some tricks. Thare tones of answer on SO on how to do it [here for why you can't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6547933/is-it-possible-to-clone-git-config-from-remote-location/6548056#6548056) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10108135/save-configuration-parameters-to-the-repository/21057383#21057383) on how you can go closer about what you want.
hope that will help.

Comment: This will change the setting locally only, right? I need the setting to be persistent across clones.

Comment: You have to copy it in a readme file or just a share a config file that the user must copy his own config directory. You can't share config file in a repository for security matter we can guess.