# git how to clone and track all branch

Tags: git, git-clone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to clone git config from remote location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6547933/is-it-possible-to-clone-git-config-from-remote-location)

As in the title, How do I clone repos and track all remote branches automatically at once?

When I clone remote repos, it only tracks `origin/master`, then I need to track other remote branches manually. Is there any way to do this automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite getting the question, but...

When you clone, you do have access to all the branches, they are there in origin.

To look at one `git checkout other_branch_name`

If those branches then get updated on the server you just need to do a `git fetch` to get all the latest versions plus any new branches that have been added.

git fetch will place them in origin/ only.  They won't be merged into your current branches until and unless you do a `git merge` (or a `git pull` which does a `fetch` AND a `merge` - but I'm avoiding that mostly these days as it's pretty dangerous if you lose focus about what's what).

Comment: Thanks, I know your method by `git co` after clone. But how about if they are many branches in repo. I have to try many times `git checkout <origin/branch>` for each remote branch, right?

Comment: You do git checkout branchname.  No origin.  This command is telling git to get the branch from tracking (origin) and make it your local development branch.