# Git submodule configuration in version control

Tags: git, git-submodules, sparse-checkout

I'm working on storing my dot files in Git, and I've run into a bit of a snag. I want to include a sparse checkout of part of the Git repository (`contrib/completion/*.bash`) as a submodule. I can get this working, but after committing my changes to the repository and cloning it to a new location, the sparse-checkout configuration is getting lost. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe it's because the sparse-checkout configuration is all stored in the .git folder of the parent repo.

Is there a good way to allow this configuration to be cloned along with the rest of the repository? I'd like to get to the point where I can clone the repo, issue `git submodule init`, then `git submodule checkout` and have only the directories I include in the `.git/modules/git/info/sparse-checkout` file checked out.

The current repository exists at https://github.com/bgshacklett/dotbash if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configuration aren't meant to be cloned.
(See for instance "[Is it possible to clone `git config` from remote location?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6548056/6309)")

But for dotfiles, after listening to GitMinutes 13 (about dotfiles, and which includes sparse checkout tricks), I would recommend **[vcsh](https://github.com/RichiH/vcsh)**.