# Add tag in "export-subst" file

Tags: git

**Situation**

We have a git workflow, where all release versions are stacked on the `master` branch, and when a commit is ready for deployment, we add a tag to it, then use `git archive` to build a bundle to be deployed.

We use a `version.txt` file, marked in `.gitattributes` with the option `export-subst`, to keep track of which commit was used to build a given archive.

**Question**

If I write `$Format:%d$` in `version.txt`, and export a tagged commit, I will have something like `(HEAD, tag, master)` written in the resulting file.

How can I have the `tag` alone ?

[edit] There is a git command which already produces that :

```
git describe --tags HEAD
```

This will output :

```
latest_tag            #if HEAD is tagged

latest_tag-5-g03cc91b #if HEAD is not tagged,
                      #and the latest tag is 5 commits ago on commit g03cc91b
```

Is there some way to have a slug replaced with this output in `version.txt` ?

Comment: I don't believe you can. The list of supported placeholders are listed in `git help log` under the `--pretty-format` section. There is not one for a tag name (and indeed, what would it do if the commit in question was not referenced by a tag?).

Comment: Really too bad this isn't possible. It would be very welcome in a world with version tags `v1.0.1` and automatically inserting the right version in source files for projects that require that metadata.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [content filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2316728/6309) which would on git checkout automatically do the exact change you want.

[image: content filter river: smudge]

<sup>(From [Pro Git book 7.2 Customizing Git - Git Attributes](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Keyword-Expansion))</sup>

You declare in a [`.gitattributes` file](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) a `smudge` script which will do the substitution for a special marker (that you want to be replaced with `git describe --tags HEAD`), without touching the other markers to be modified by `export-subst` on `git archive`.

Then you call [`git archive`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive), which should (not tested) replace the rest.

Comment: Ok, it could be a workaround. This leads to another question : do you know a way to share the .git/config (or at least the relevant part for smudging/cleaning) along with the repository ?

Comment: @LeGEC the smudge script and the .gitattributes are in the repo (so sharable with the rest of the repo). But the declaration in the .git/config remains to be done by the user (you could version a script the user has to execute to add that config). A config is never shared (http://stackoverflow.com/a/6548056/6309)