# How can I share a git configuration?

Tags: git, git-flow

I've initiated a new git repository using `git flow`, done a commit or two and pushed.

When I clone the repository in a new directory and run a `git flow` command I get the error:

```
Fatal: Not a gitflow-enabled repo yet. Please run 'git flow init' first.
```

The reason for the error is that the `.git/config` file in the newly cloned directory doesn't contain the git flow configuration.

**How can I push/share the configuration so any clone of the repository will have the correct configuration?**

Comment: Yes the `tag` I use is non-default.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### You cannot directly share you config

The contents of the `.git` folder are (intended to be) specific to an individual install.

### Alternative

Instead of trying to directly share your config, consider adding a script to the repository to setup whatever config you want to share. e.g. add a file named `bin/setup` to the repository with these contents:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# simple
git flow init -d

# override stuff or whatever
git config gitflow.prefix.versiontag ""
git config gitflow.prefix.feature ""
```

Commit it:

```
-> chmod +x bin/setup
-> git add bin/setup
-> git commit -m "adding a setup script to ensure consistent config"
```

And run it on new clones:

```
-> git clone ....
-> cd project
-> bin/setup
-> git config -l --local
...
gitflow.branch.master=master
gitflow.branch.develop=development
gitflow.prefix.versiontag=
gitflow.prefix.feature=
gitflow.prefix.release=release/
gitflow.prefix.hotfix=hotfix/
gitflow.prefix.support=support/
```

Comment: +1. That is the hack I was mentioning in my comment below (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23723461/how-can-i-share-a-git-configuration/23726067#comment36463591_23723526)

Comment: It's rather hard to answer a git question without (intentionally or not) stating something you've already written somewhere =).

Comment: paying it forward mate, thanks for a great solution.

Comment: Cool hack, but I have encountered a problem `git flow init -d` will fail if the develop and/or master branches are not present. I solved the problem by first pre-configuring git flow and then run `git flow init -d`.

Answer (score 0):

[This tutorial](http://yakiloo.com/getting-started-git-flow/) does mention

> Now that you’ve cloned the Repository, **you should run the `git flow init` command** on your local Repository as well to get your local Git configuration to match that of your remote as follows:
>
> ```
> git flow init
> ```
>
> This should automatically switch you into the develop branch and you should now do a Git pull from your remote to ensure that you have the latest develop branch locally by running the following command:
>
> ```
> git pull origin develop
> ```
>
> Now that you have your local Repository matching that of your remote on both master and develop you should continue to start a feature branch.
>   git flow feature

So that reflects the error message you have: git clone isn't enough, you need to re-create the git flow config with the `git flow init` command.
(Since a [local git config is never shared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6548056/6309))

Comment: I do understand that, as I wrote that the error is because the configuration isn't shared. My question is if there is any way I can share some or all git configuration?

Comment: @SimonW `git flow init` should re-create that git flow config for you then.

Comment: @SimonW as I mentioned, you don't share a git config, by design (git flow or no git flow).

Comment: I'll try to explain myself better, I understand that I can't share the `.git/config`, is there any other way/method/hack to share some/any git configuration? (and sorry if I'm bugging)

Comment: @SimonW you are not bugging, and this is a very valid question, but a/ not really (unless you version the config file, and then symlink the `.git/config` to it once cloned, but that is really not a good practice), b/ I wonder what config you would need to share and which isn't appropriately re-created by the `git flow init` command after a `git clone` of a git flow-managed repo?

Comment: thank you for your help! My current need can easily be re-created with the `git flow init` but as many programmers work on this repository I wish to make it as foolproof as I can.

Comment: @SimonW if they are all using the same workflow manager (`git flow`), then they will have to follow an initialization step like `git flow init` (or a custom wrapper like AD7six's answer, but I wouldn't recommend it, as it is one more wrapper around a wrapper)