# Usage of git flow init when team members clone the remote repository

Tags: git, github, git-flow

Suppose I have cloned a remote repository (which again belongs to me, say from [github.com](https://www.github.com)) and I have initialized git flow. As you may know, `git flow init` will create `develop`  branch and create the prefixes for feature, bugfix etc. So far fine.

If I try to execute `git flow init` again on the same repository, git already says that:
`Already initialized for gitflow.`
`To force reinitialization, use: git flow init -f`

That means git stores the state of initialization within the git repository (in `.git` folder). Now, if I push the  `develop` branch, it reflects in the remote repository, which is as expected.

Now, if another team member clones from this remote repository in his local machine, he again has to initialize using `git flow init` (if he wants to use `git flow`).

I expected that it should have given the output: `Already initialized for gitflow.`
`To force reinitialization, use: git flow init -f` in his machine, but that is not the case.

Can you please clarify as to why every team member has to execute `git flow init` in his local machine after they clone from the remote repository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is you need to initialize `git flow` after every `git clone`.

The initialization of `git flow` operates on two sides:

1. create the correct branch structure (ex. the missing develop branch).
   You gonna need to push the new branch.
2. update the local `.git/config` file with all the information given to `git flow`.
   This is a local configuration and cannot be pushed. After a successful `git clone`, the user needs to run a `git flow init` to allow git to update the local configuration.

You may found this reading useful: [How can I share a git configuration?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23726067/484674)