# How to save config for merged-remotes in a git repository?

Tags: git, github

I have a merged-remote so that a push goes to both the github server and to a file system folder.

I've added the merged-remote by using:

`git remote set-url --add origin "file:////server/folder/myrepo"`

The repo's config file then has this in the origin remote section:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = http://enterprise/folder/myrepo
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = file:////server/folder/myrepo
```

I can then use `git push` to send updates to both our github server and to a file system folder.

However these settings aren't saved to the repo. If I clone the repo back down from github server the config looks like:

```
[remote "origin"]
        url = http://enterprise/folder/myrepo
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

The second url setting is now gone, and `git commit --all` doesn't see the `config` file as something to commit. How do I get this second remote url to save?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to clone git config from remote location?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6547933/is-it-possible-to-clone-git-config-from-remote-location)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything stored in `.git/config` is purely local, including remote information. Your initial remote isn't stored either; this gets created when you clone, and is based on the URL you used to create your clone.

For more about why `.git/config` is not shared, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6547933/is-it-possible-to-clone-git-config-from-remote-location/6548056#6548056).

Comment: I see, its a security risk to include the config file. I also see that this is a duplicate of a number of questions now. Thanks for the response.