# How can I commit/push a git alias (in .git/config)?

Tags: git, config, alias, git-config

I can't find a way to push the `alias.*` settings in `.git/config` on to my remote repo.
Is there away to do this.

I don't want to make a global alias because some of the alias is specific for each repo and then we have to maintain all the alias manual on each machine.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot: a config is never exported ([for security reason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6548056/6309))

You can version your `.git/config` as a regular file (by copying in your working tree and adding it to the index, and committing it).
But you need to add a `README` asking the user to review its content, and symlink that to your local `.git/config`.

You could find a more detailed process (to version a config file) in:

- "[Using conditional configuration files with Git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24498888/6309)"
- "[Storing git config as part of the repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18330114/6309)" (using an `include` procedure)