# Keep Git merge strategy in repo

Tags: git

## Short

Globally in `~/.gitconfig` as well as per repo in `.git/config` some settings (such as merge strategies) can be configured. None of these options is kept in the repo itself. Is there a way to define merge strategies that live in the repo (just as `.gitigrore` and `.gitattributes`)?

## Background

Assumed I have some sort of boilerplate git repo that is meant to be forked and used as a starting point for certain projects. Also since the master boilerplate can change but should be in sync with its 'child projects' (or vice versa), I want to add the boilerplate as upstream. This way I am able to `git fetch upstream && git merge upstream/master` from time to time to keep up with the changes in the boilerplate.

Now: Certain files will exist in all repos and should intentionally NOT in sync. Take `README.md` as an obvious example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to define merge strategies that live in the repo (just as .gitignore and .gitattributes)?

Not with native git: anything config-related is a bit too dangerous to be kept in the repo, and should be set by the user explicitly.
See "[Is it possible to clone git config from remote location?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6548056/6309)".

One workaround would be to version a "`setup`" script which would be in charge to perform the requested `git config` commands.
Each user would have to execute it once after a `git clone`.

Comment: A setup script seems to be an acceptable approach. Merci!