# Inherit bare config configuration when cloning

Tags: git

In bare repository I have the following configuration

```
[core]
    filemode = false
```

How to inherit this configuration when cloning the repository?

If I do `git clone //server/repo` I have `filemode = true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[A config is never cloned (for security reason)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6548056/6309).

The simplest way to enforce that is:

```
git config --global core.filemode false
```

That will apply to all local repos.

(The default for that config is `true`, when `core.filemode` is not specified in the local config file of the repo).