# configuring conditional push in gitconfig

Tags: git

In our team we had two repositories till now. One was Development and other was Production.

So we configured the gitconfig global file as default fetch from Production and default push to Development.

Now we have introduced a third repository named Common. Whoever clones from 'Common' should have default push configured as 'Common'. Since we have configured 'Development' as default push repository in global, the default push is pointing to 'Development' even inside 'Common' repository when it is cloned.

How can i make something like below in gitconfig global?

```
if (cloned repository from Production)
then 
    default push is Development

if  (cloned repository from Common)
then 
    default push is Common
```

Comment: One way would be to set the `remote.pushDefault = Common` variable in the *local* config for the `Common` repo, since that will [override](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#_git_config) the value set in the global config.

Comment: @EnricoCampidoglio: Now i have two default push paths after the change you recommended.

Comment: @SSHedge Could you please elaborate? What command did you run? How does your `[remote]` config section look like?

Comment: Executed below command inside the repository cloned from Common:
`git config remote.origin.pushurl Common`

But the following command gives me two push paths:
`git remote -v
origin  Development (push)
origin  Common (push)`

Comment: I see what you mean. The global `pushurl` variable can't be overridden locally; in fact, Git is going to show you both of them but only consider the global one. In order to remove the _local_ `pushurl` variable you can run `git config --unset remote.origin.pushurl`. Please, see my answer below for a different approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your global configuration file contains something like this:

```
[remote "origin"]
pushurl = http://url/to/development
```

here's one way to achieve what you want:

1. Define a new remote in the `Common` repository that points to the same URL as `origin`:

   ```
   git remote add common http://url/to/common
   ```
2. Set the `remote.pushDefault` variable in the *local* configuration file to `common`:

   ```
   git config remote.pushDefault common
   ```

The `remote.pushDefault` setting tells Git to push using the URL defined in the specified remote instead of `origin`.

Here's from the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config):

> **remote.pushDefault**
>   The remote to push to by default. Overrides
>   `branch.<name>.remote` for all branches, and is overridden by
>   `branch.<name>.pushRemote` for specific branches.

In this case, the push URL for `origin` is defined in the global configuration file but the `Common` repository is going to use the push URL defined in its own remote, named `common`.

Comment: If i do this change then this setting remains till i remove the cloned repo from Common. If i clone a new repo from Common then again i need to perform these step. Isn't it?

Comment: Correct – the local config file of a repo [isn't shared remotely](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6548056/26396). But I guess you already have a way to share the global `remote.origin.pushurl` setting. These local settings could be shared in a similar fashion.

Comment: Thanks Enrico. That does the job.