# Push git config file settings to remote URL

Tags: git, git-config

Is there any way .git/config can be replicated onto a remote server. I would like to modify http postBuffer at the remote url end using command line. Does git push replicate config as well.

Answer (score 11):

The config remains purely local, for security reason, as [I mentioned in 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6548056/6309).
So `git push` does *not* replicate config as well.

One way would be to store a config file as a regular file in the repo, with instruction to set it up once cloned.

But directly change a config setting on a remote server from a client-side command-line is not possible.

Not unless you can establish a direct connection (for instance `ssh`) onto the server, to the the repository path, and execute a `git config` command there.

Comment: Thanks @vonc . Is there any way i can modify commit size at the server end

Comment: @Arjun It depends on what is the "server end". If you can access it through ssh, then yes.

Comment: I think making a git hook to make the local setting again on post-checkout should work too.

Comment: @paradroid Don't forget to come back here and let us know of what you have created!