# How to prevent git merge if current branch has uncommitted changes

Tags: git

It's possible to `git merge` even if current branch has uncommitted changes. Example:

```
git checkout featureA
ls >> foo
git commit -am "added featureA"
git checkout dev
ls >> bar                    # current branch now has uncommitted changes
git merge featureA
```

I wonder if it's possible to configure git to always fail as long as current branch has uncommitted changes, just to make the merge safer.

Comment: Add them to the index? Otherwise, I'm not sure how this is unsafe. Git will avoid merging if things are unsafe (see also "Pre-merge Checks": https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#_pre_merge_checks).

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was to declare a Git alias to override the `merge` command and check the state of your working-directory and index prior to performing the operation.

Turns out it's not possible to overwrite an exiting Git command with a Git alias (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538774/is-it-possible-to-override-git-command-by-git-alias) for more info) but you could define a shell-level alias.

To keep things simple, perhaps it would be better to define an alias called `safemerge`. You could also define an additional alias to make detecting a clean state easy.

Define these as aliases in your `.gitconfig`:

```
isclean = !(git status --porcelain | grep . && exit 1 || exit 0)
safemerge = !git isclean && git-merge
```

Now, when you go to merge you can run `git safemerge` and the merge will not happen if you have uncommitted changes.