# Automatically force git push for branches with a certain prefix

Tags: git, git-push

Here's my workflow:

- `git checkout -b my_private_prefix/branch master`
- *hack hack hack*
- `git push`
- *hack hack hack*
- `git rebase -i ; git push --force`
- *pull request*

It is OK to `push --force` here, because I am the only one who works on branches with the private prefix (everyone on the team has a different prefix). My question: **can I make git automatically force pushes when the current branch name starts with my private prefix?**

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer you are looking for, but you  could create a git alias like pushf that adds in the -f flag. You could also try to override the default push, but you have to go through some work (see [Is it possible to override git command by git alias?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538774/is-it-possible-to-override-git-command-by-git-alias)) and have it look at the branch to push and optionally add the -f flag.