# Git - Auto rebase while pushing

Tags: git, push, gerrit, rebase, pull

While working on a git project, I want to run a `git pull --rebase` before each `git push`. However, some developers in my team often forget to call `git pull --rebase` before pushing. So, Git/Gerrit automatically performs a merge which creates a malformed commit message.I want to avoid this auto merging.

I want to configure clients git so that when developers run a `git push`, a `git pull --rebase` should automatically occurs. Is there any way?

Comment: Trivially, you could make all your developers create an alias that does this and publicly shame anyone who doesn't use it instead of `git push`. :P

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: More seriously though, what do you mean by *setup git*? Technically, all the client's git configurations are part of git.

Comment: I mean clients git configuration. @merlin2011

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tell all your developers to add the following to their `.git/config` files after cloning. Then require all of them to use `git goodpush` instead of `git push`.

```
[alias]
        goodpush = "!git pull --rebase && git push"
```

This configuration can also be placed inside the `.gitconfig` file in the user's home directory to avoid doing it for each repository that is cloned.

Note that the name of the alias **cannot be `push`**, for reasons discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3538791/391161), so you will have to provide some incentives or train your developers to no longer use `push` directly.

On the plus side, since you get a malformed commit message whenever somebody does use `push` accidentally, you will immediately know whom to speak with if such a use occurs.

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan, Not in the current implementation, no. You would have to pass arguments appropriately based on what arguments you expect and want to pass to each of the two commands.

Comment: how arguments are used in aliases?

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan, That is addressed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3321492/391161). Please note the comments under the question and each answer before using it.

Comment: You are awesome! @merlin2011

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan, Thanks and good luck training your developers to switch! :)

Comment: In case working with arguments, use `git config --global alias.goodpush '!rebaseAndPush() { git pull --rebase &&  git push origin HEAD:refs/for/$1; }; rebaseAndPush'`